# How can I create a Set of Sets in Python?

Tags: python, collections, nested, set

I'm trying to make a set of sets in Python.  I can't figure out how to do it.

Starting with the empty set `xx`:

```
xx = set([])
# Now we have some other set, for example
elements = set([2,3,4])
xx.add(elements)
```

but I get

```
TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
```

or

```
TypeError: unhashable type: 'set'
```

Is it possible to have a set of sets in Python?

I am dealing with a large collection of sets and I want to be able to not have to deal duplicate sets (a set B of sets A1, A2, ...., An would "cancel" two sets if Ai = Aj)

Answer (score 149):

Python's complaining because the inner `set` objects are mutable and thus not hashable. The solution is to use [`frozenset`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#frozenset) for the inner sets, to indicate that you have no intention of modifying them.

```
xx = set([])
# Nested sets must be frozen
elements = frozenset([2,3,4])
xx.add(elements)
```

Answer (score 75):

People already mentioned that you can do this with a [frozenset()](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#frozenset), so I will just add a code how to achieve this:

For example you want to create a set of sets from the following list of lists:

```
t = [[], [1, 2], [5], [1, 2, 5], [1, 2, 3, 4], [1, 2, 3, 6]]
```

you can create your set in the following way:

```
t1 = set(frozenset(i) for i in t)
```

Comment: or you can use map!
`set(map(frozenset, t))`

Answer (score 20):

Use [`frozenset`](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#frozenset) inside.

Comment: Perhaps you could give a few pointers about mutable/immutable objects in Python since he's new?

Comment: @Seth: I could, but mutability is not a factor.

Comment: Thanks very much! Just reading re: mutability now. Seems like a set of lists may also work but frozenset seems to get it done. Thanks again!

Comment: @Ignacio I thought that members in sets and keys in dicts had to be hash-able and therefore immutable.

Comment: Hashability and mutability are not necessarily mutually-exclusive. It just so happens that most of the basic Python types share a pattern.

Answer (score 3):

So I had the exact same problem. I wanted to make a data structure that works as a set of sets. The problem is that the sets must contain *immutable* objects. So, what you can do is simply make it as a set of tuples. That worked fine for me!

```
A = set()
A.add( (2,3,4) )##adds the element
A.add( (2,3,4) )##does not add the same element
A.add( (2,3,5) )##adds the element, because it is different!
```

Comment: In tuples, the element order matters. Thus `A.add( (4,3,2)); A.add((2,4,3)); A.add((2,3,4))` will add three distinct elements, while the original question is about "set of sets", which implies that `(2,3,4)`, `(4,3,2)`, `(2,4,3)` are the same.