# Removing duplicate interaction pairs in python sets

Tags: python, set, tuples

suppose you have a list of tuples in a python set:

```
>>> pairs = set( [(0,1),(0,1),(1,0)] )
>>> print pairs
set([(0, 1), (1, 0)])
```

Obviously, the first two elements are duplicates and according
to the definition of a set, "pairs" only holds unique elements.

However, in my particular case the tuple (i,j) defines an interaction pair. Thus,
(i,j) and (j,i) are the same. I need an effective way to reduce all duplicate 
elements. Computation time is crucial for me since the total set could easily contain a number of element as large as 10**6. I expect the following result:

```
>>> pairs = set( [(0,1),(0,1),(1,0)] )
>>> pairs = remove_duplicate_interactions(pairs)
>>> print pairs
set([0,1]) or set([1,0])
```

I am thankful for any hint.

Edit:

Someone asked about the context. This is supposed to be used for particle simulations.
Due to symmetry conditions, the force of particle i acting on j is the same as the force of j acting on i. The reduction of computation time is thus 50 %.

Comment: No ordering in any dimension. set([(i,j),(k,l),..]) = set([ (k,l),(i,j),..]) = set([(j,i),(l,k),...]) ...

Answer (score 10):

How about:

```
In [4]: pairs = set( [(0,1),(0,1),(1,0),(1,2),(1,0),(2,1)] )

In [5]: set((a,b) if a<=b else (b,a) for a,b in pairs)
Out[5]: set([(0, 1), (1, 2)])
```

Comment: How is it even possible you people always find single-line solutions ?

Comment: @RakulanS.: devise harder problems :)

Answer (score 4):

```
>>> pairs = [(0,1),(0,1),(1,0)]
>>> set(tuple(sorted(p)) for p in pairs)
set([(0, 1)])
```

Comment: Extremely helpful

Answer (score 3):

I would subtype `tuple` and always make the pair ordered:

```
class InteractionPair(tuple):
    def __new__(cls, a, b):
        if a <= b:
            return tuple.__new__(cls, (a, b))
        return tuple.__new__(cls, (b, a))
```

Example:

```
>>> set([InteractionPair(0, 1), InteractionPair(1, 0)])
set([(0, 1)])
```

This can also be applied to a list of standard tuples:

```
from itertools import starmap
pairs = [(0, 1), (0, 1), (1, 0)]
print set(starmap(InteractionPair, pairs))
```

**Edit**: Her are some timings, using a list of 1000000 random pairs:

```
In [14]: timeit set(starmap(InteractionPair, pairs))
1 loops, best of 3: 742 ms per loop

In [15]: timeit set((a,b) if a<=b else (b,a) for a,b in pairs)
1 loops, best of 3: 258 ms per loop

In [16]: timeit set(tuple(sorted(p)) for p in pairs)
1 loops, best of 3: 1.02 s per loop
```

As far as performance is concerned, the [solution by aix](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9502512/279627) wins.

Comment: @larsmans: Not sure if it really is.  This approach might sometimes be useful, but you would need to know more about the context to judge if this is really worth it.

Comment: I like object-oriented approaches, so this seems quite elegant to me too. But how about efficiency ? Intuitively, this seems quite computation heavy ?!

Comment: @RakulanS.: Added a few simple timings.  It's not that bad.

Answer (score 2):

If you can use `frozenset` instead of tuples, you can store each interaction pair as a set. An alternative is to store all your tuples in some canonical form (e.g., so that `i < j`). No idea if this has a speed advantage over frozenset, but the simpler the form, the faster python will be able to hash it and compute the set of unique elements.

Answer (score 0):

```
pairs = set(frozenset(p) for p in ((0,1),(0,1),(1,0)) )
```

Will achieve what you need. See my answer here for further information: [How do I perform deep equality comparisons of two lists of tuples?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9360057/how-do-i-perform-deep-equality-comparisons-of-two-lists-of-tuples/9360107#9360107)

If necessary, you can reconstruct these as pairs afterwards.