# How to check the duplicate pair in excel?

Tags: excel, duplicates

I tried to find the pairs in multiple columns in excel.

```
abc def  1 <-duplicate 1
ael fjw  1
dlf qwr  1
cvz god  1 <-duplicate 2
abc def -1 <-duplicate 1
slf erw -1
def abc -1 <-duplicate 1
god cvz -1 <-dupllicate 2
cnv odf -1
```

After that, I should eliminate the pairs that have the value -1. 
I tried [excel duplicate values pairs in multiple column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16823468/excel-duplicate-values-pairs-in-multiple-column) post, but it showed an unexpected result.

If it is hard to run in Excel, it is okay to suggest the code in python or R.
In particular, I checked the post [Removing duplicate interaction pairs in python sets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9502469/removing-duplicate-interaction-pairs-in-python-sets) which is a similar problem in python. 
But this example is corresponding to the numerical value.

Also, if there are any problems with my question, please correct them.

Comment: =A1=B1 then dragged down will do the test giving true or false. Then =if(a1=b1,1,-1) will give the result. Then I would just sort on the result and delete.

Comment: @Solar Mike Thank you for your comment. I tried your code, but I'm still ambiguous. I want to check if there are any same pairs with 'abc-def' in other rows. 1 and -1 is specific value, not true/positive representor. But your suggestion looks like checking if A1=B1 or not. (i.e. whether abc=def or not)

Comment: =A1=B1 means check to evaluate if the contents of cell A1 is equal to the contents of cell B1, whether the contents are text or numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your first row of data is in `A1:C1`, this formula in `D1`:

`=IF(AND(SUM(COUNTIFS(A$1:A1,INDEX(A1:B1,{1;2}),B$1:B1,INDEX(A1:B1,{2;1})))>1,C1=-1),"Delete","")`

and copied down.

If your version of Excel does not use the semicolon as row- or column-separator within array constants then the parts

`{1;2}`

and

`{2;1}`

will require amendment.