# Why is it not possible to have a set as an element of a set?

Tags: python, set

It gives me error while creating `{{2}, 3, 4}` set element inside a set.

**Error:**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: unhashable type: 'set'
```

Is there any alternative way to do that?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5931291/how-can-i-create-a-set-of-sets-in-python

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Python, in general, mutable types like `set` are not [hashable](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-hashable). It's not just a coincidence that they can't be used as `set` elements or `dict` keys—that's actually the whole point:

> An object is hashable if it has a hash value which never changes during its lifetime (it needs a `__hash__()` method), and can be compared to other objects (it needs an `__eq__()` method). Hashable objects which compare equal must have the same hash value.
>
> Hashability makes an object usable as a dictionary key and a set member, because these data structures use the hash value internally.
>
> All of Python’s immutable built-in objects are hashable, while no mutable containers (such as lists or dictionaries) are. Objects which are instances of user-defined classes are hashable by default; they all compare unequal (except with themselves), and their hash value is derived from their `id()`.

The [`frozenset`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#set-types-set-frozenset) type exists for pretty much this purpose:

> There are currently two built-in set types, `set` and `frozenset`. The `set` type is mutable — the contents can be changed using methods like `add()` and `remove()`. Since it is mutable, it has no hash value and cannot be used as either a dictionary key or as an element of another set. The `frozenset` type is immutable and hashable — its contents cannot be altered after it is created; it can therefore be used as a dictionary key or as an element of another set.

Comment: How hashing is used internally in a `set`?

Answer (score 2):

Sets can only contain hashable objects.  But sets themselves are not hashable.  So a set can't contain another set.

(Aside from that, your code has a syntax error because `{2}.3` is invalid syntax.  But if you change it to `{{2}, 3, 4}` it still won't work, for the reason I mentioned above.)

Answer (score 1):

Even though their items must all be immutable/hashable types, sets themselves are a mutable/nonhashable type.  You can either add or remove items from a set using methods such as `set.add`, `set.pop`, or `set.remove`.  Thus, you cannot put a set inside another set because the item might be changed at any time.

Instead, you can use a [`frozenset`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#set-types-set-frozenset), which is an immutable/hashable set:

```
>>> {frozenset({2}), 3,4}
set([frozenset([2]), 3, 4])
>>>
```

Keep in mind however that this only works because frozensets cannot be changed after they are created (there is no way to add or remove items).