# python dictionary match keys in two dictionaries when the keys are combinations of two strings

Tags: python, dictionary

I have two python dictionaries:

```
dictA = {('a','b') : 1,('a','c') : 3,('b','c') : 1}
dictB = {('b','a') : 4,('a','d') : 6,('b','c') : 2}
```

I want to compare the keys of dictA and dictB for common keys. I have tried

```
comm = set(dictA.keys()) & set(dictB.keys())
```

But, this will only return `('b','c')`.

But,in my case, first key in both the dictionaries are same i.e. `dictA[('a','b')]` is  equivalent to `dictB[('b','a')]`. How to do this ??

Comment: Your first keys are no the same. `In [32]: ('a', 'b') == ('b', 'a')
Out[32]: False`

Comment: Because `('a', 'b')` is tuple, it's not set.

Comment: What is the expected result? Will there be duplicates in the keys?

Comment: The expected result is [('b', 'a'), ('b', 'c')] or [('a', 'b'), ('b', 'c')]

Comment: @user1894087 Although it needs to take some time, I have a good solution!

Comment: Your statement `dictA[('a','b')] is equivalent to dictB[('b','a')` is **false** for both the keys as for the values they return. The order of elements in a tuple is significant (unless the elements have the same value), and creates different keys.

Answer (score 1):

I have a more compact method.

I think it's more readable and easy to understand. You can refer as below:

These are your vars:

```
dictA = {('a','b') : 1,('a','c') : 3,('b','c') : 1}
dictB = {('b','a') : 4,('a','d') : 6,('b','c') : 2}
```

According your requirement to solve this problem:

```
print [ a for a in dictA if set(a) in [ set(i) for i in dictB.keys()]]
```

So you can get answer you want.

```
[('b', 'c'), ('a', 'b')]
```

Answer (score 1):

Another solution, albeit less elegant than what Tony has suggested:

```
setA = [ frozenset(i) for i in dictA.keys() ]
setB = [ frozenset(i) for i in dictB.keys() ]
result = set(setA) & set(setB)
print( [tuple(i) for i in result] )
```

It uses [frozenset](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5931291/how-can-i-create-a-set-of-sets-in-python) in order to construct two sets of sets. Here's the kind of output you're gonna get:

```
[('b', 'c'), ('b', 'a')]
```

Answer (score 0):

That `('b','c')` is returned is the correct answer. The tuple `('a', 'b')` is not the same as the tuple `('b', 'a')`.