# Unique value from the list of sets

Tags: python-3.x, string, set

I have a list e.g

```
['abc', 'acb', 'bac', 'foo', 'bca', 'cab', 'cba']
```

and

```py
list(map(set, x))

out:

[{'a', 'b', 'c'},
 {'a', 'b', 'c'},
 {'a', 'b', 'c'},
 {'f', 'o'},
 {'a', 'b', 'c'},
 {'a', 'b', 'c'},
 {'a', 'b', 'c'}]
```

I would like to receive a set from the set I mean. Expected output:

```
[ {'a', 'b', 'c'},
 {'f', 'o'}]
```

My second question. How to get a dictionary of counts?

```
{{'a', 'b', 'c'} : 6,
 {'f', 'o'} : 1}}
```

Comment: What is your question exactly? It's not very clear.

Comment: I want to leave unique values ​​from the list of sets.

Comment: How big is your list? I've got an easy solution that works quite slowly for big lists. Can you tell me the scale of your list? (10^3 for example)

Comment: My list has 1500000 elements, but you can show me, I'm not looking for a solution but inspiration, unless you mean loops

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your first question, [How can I create a Set of Sets in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5931291/how-can-i-create-a-set-of-sets-in-python) might be what you are looking for. As for your second question, the simplest way is to use Counter. [This](https://realpython.com/python-counter/) link may be useful for you.

Code:

```
from collections import Counter
x = ['abc', 'acb', 'bac', 'foo', 'bca', 'cab', 'cba']
a = list(map(frozenset, x))
print(set(a))
print(Counter(a))
```

Output:

`{frozenset({'a', 'c', 'b'}), frozenset({'o', 'f'})}`

`Counter({frozenset({'a', 'c', 'b'}): 6, frozenset({'o', 'f'}): 1})`

Comment: On point! I didn't know frozenset. Thank you!