# permutations with unique values

Tags: python, permutation, python-itertools

itertools.permutations generates where its elements are treated as unique based on their position, not on their value. So basically I want to avoid duplicates like this:

```
>>> list(itertools.permutations([1, 1, 1]))
[(1, 1, 1), (1, 1, 1), (1, 1, 1), (1, 1, 1), (1, 1, 1), (1, 1, 1)]
```

Filtering afterwards is not possible because the amount of permutations is too large in my case.

Does anybody know of a suitable algorithm for this?

Thank you very much!

**EDIT:**

What I basically want is the following:

```
x = itertools.product((0, 1, 'x'), repeat=X)
x = sorted(x, key=functools.partial(count_elements, elem='x'))
```

which is not possible because `sorted` creates a list and the output of itertools.product is too large.

Sorry, I should have described the actual problem.

Comment: What's too large? The TOTAL permutations or the UNIQUE permutations or both?

Comment: There is an even faster solution than the accepted answer (an implementation of Knuth's Algorithm L) given [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12837695/429982)

Comment: You are looking for permutations of **[Multisets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiset)**. See the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40289807/4408538) by Bill Bell below.

Comment: Did you try `for x in permutation() set.add(x)`?

Comment: Maybe a better title for this question would be "distinct permutations".  Better still, "distinct permutations of a list with duplicates".

Comment: In case you want to just get the number of unique/distinct permutations (not the permutations themselves), see: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1759860/141182

Answer (score 64, accepted):

```
class unique_element:
    def __init__(self,value,occurrences):
        self.value = value
        self.occurrences = occurrences

def perm_unique(elements):
    eset=set(elements)
    listunique = [unique_element(i,elements.count(i)) for i in eset]
    u=len(elements)
    return perm_unique_helper(listunique,[0]*u,u-1)

def perm_unique_helper(listunique,result_list,d):
    if d < 0:
        yield tuple(result_list)
    else:
        for i in listunique:
            if i.occurrences > 0:
                result_list[d]=i.value
                i.occurrences-=1
                for g in  perm_unique_helper(listunique,result_list,d-1):
                    yield g
                i.occurrences+=1




a = list(perm_unique([1,1,2]))
print(a)
```

result:

```
[(2, 1, 1), (1, 2, 1), (1, 1, 2)]
```

EDIT (how this works):

I rewrote the above program to be longer but more readable.

I usually have a hard time explaining how something works, but let me try.
In order to understand how this works, you have to understand a similar but simpler program that would yield all permutations with repetitions.

```
def permutations_with_replacement(elements,n):
    return permutations_helper(elements,[0]*n,n-1)#this is generator

def permutations_helper(elements,result_list,d):
    if d<0:
        yield tuple(result_list)
    else:
        for i in elements:
            result_list[d]=i
            all_permutations = permutations_helper(elements,result_list,d-1)#this is generator
            for g in all_permutations:
                yield g
```

This program is obviously much simpler:
d stands for depth in permutations_helper and has two functions. One function is the stopping condition of our recursive algorithm, and the other is for the result list that is passed around.

Instead of returning each result, we yield it. If there were no function/operator `yield` we would have to push the result in some queue at the point of the stopping condition. But this way, once the stopping condition is met, the result is propagated through all stacks up to the caller. That is the purpose of
`for g in  perm_unique_helper(listunique,result_list,d-1): yield g`
so each result is propagated up to caller.

Back to the original program:
we have a list of unique elements. Before we can use each element, we have to check how many of them are still available to push onto result_list. Working with this program is very similar to `permutations_with_replacement`. The difference is that each element cannot be repeated more times than it is in perm_unique_helper.

Comment: I'm trying to understand how this works, but I'm stumped. Could you please provide some kind of commentary?

Comment: @Nathan I edited answer and refined code. Feel free to post extra questions you have.

Comment: Nice piece of code. You re-implemented `itertools.Counter`, right?

Comment: I am not familiar with itertools Counter. This code is more of an example and for educational purposes, but less for production, due to performance issues. If one needs better solution I would suggest iterative/non-recursing solution originating from Narayana Pandita and also explained by the Donad Knuth in _the art of computer programming_  with possible python implementation at http://stackoverflow.com/a/12837695/429982

Comment: I recreated this with `itertools.Counter`, but it seems your code is quicker :)

Comment: This solution seems to work great, but because of its recursive nature I can't discern a pattern with which the tuples are generated. Is there a way to guarantee that the tuples will be generated in lexicographic order?

Comment: @alexw If you observe that order in witch elements are picked is depended on order of eset . They are pushed from the end of list as depth is going from high to low. This is position where elemets are inserted it does not take mutch to fix this. 
I hope it helps. https://gist.github.com/ra1u/a12f6cd85d4b46b7d8d63d47c69e656f

Answer (score 65):

Because sometimes new questions are marked as duplicates and their authors are referred to this question it may be important to mention that **sympy** has an iterator for this purpose.

```
>>> from sympy.utilities.iterables import multiset_permutations
>>> list(multiset_permutations([1,1,1]))
[[1, 1, 1]]
>>> list(multiset_permutations([1,1,2]))
[[1, 1, 2], [1, 2, 1], [2, 1, 1]]
```

Comment: This is the only answer that explicitly identifies what the OP is really looking for (i.e. permutations of **[Multisets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiset)**).

Answer (score 29):

This relies on the implementation detail that any permutation of a sorted iterable are in sorted order unless they are duplicates of prior permutations.

```
from itertools import permutations

def unique_permutations(iterable, r=None):
    previous = tuple()
    for p in permutations(sorted(iterable), r):
        if p > previous:
            previous = p
            yield p

for p in unique_permutations('cabcab', 2):
    print p
```

gives

```
('a', 'a')
('a', 'b')
('a', 'c')
('b', 'a')
('b', 'b')
('b', 'c')
('c', 'a')
('c', 'b')
('c', 'c')
```

Comment: works perfectly well but slower than the accepted solution. Thank you!

Comment: This is not true in newer versions of Python. For instance, in Python 3.7.1, `list(itertools.permutations([1,2,2], 3))` returns `[(1, 2, 2), (1, 2, 2), (2, 1, 2), (2, 2, 1), (2, 1, 2), (2, 2, 1)]`.

Comment: @KirkStrauser: You are correct.  The statement "any permutation of a sorted iterable are in sorted order" wasn't even true of older versions of Python.  I tested Python versions back through 2.7 and found your result accurate.  Interestingly enough it doesn't invalidate the algorithm.  It does produce permutations such that only max permutations at any point are original.

Comment: @KirkStrauser: I must ammend.  You are incorrect.  I went to edit my answer and read more closely what I wrote.  My statement had a qualifier that made it correct: "any permutation of a sorted iterable are in sorted order *unless they are duplicates of prior permutations*."

Answer (score 20):

Roughly as fast as Luka Rahne's answer, but shorter & simpler, IMHO.

```
def unique_permutations(elements):
    if len(elements) == 1:
        yield (elements[0],)
    else:
        unique_elements = set(elements)
        for first_element in unique_elements:
            remaining_elements = list(elements)
            remaining_elements.remove(first_element)
            for sub_permutation in unique_permutations(remaining_elements):
                yield (first_element,) + sub_permutation

>>> list(unique_permutations((1,2,3,1)))
[(1, 1, 2, 3), (1, 1, 3, 2), (1, 2, 1, 3), ... , (3, 1, 2, 1), (3, 2, 1, 1)]
```

It works recursively by setting the first element (iterating through all unique elements), and iterating through the permutations for all remaining elements.

Let's go through the `unique_permutations` of (1,2,3,1) to see how it works:

- `unique_elements` are 1,2,3
- Let's iterate through them: `first_element` starts with 1.

  - `remaining_elements` are [2,3,1] (ie. 1,2,3,1 minus the first 1)
  - We iterate (recursively) through the permutations of the remaining elements: (1, 2, 3), (1, 3, 2), (2, 1, 3), (2, 3, 1), (3, 1, 2), (3, 2, 1)
  - For each `sub_permutation`, we insert the `first_element`: (**1**,1,2,3), (**1**,1,3,2), ... and yield the result.
- Now we iterate to `first_element` = 2, and do the same as above.

  - `remaining_elements` are [1,3,1] (ie. 1,2,3,1 minus the first 2)
  - We iterate through the permutations of the remaining elements: (1, 1, 3), (1, 3, 1), (3, 1, 1)
  - For each `sub_permutation`, we insert the `first_element`: (**2**, 1, 1, 3), (**2**, 1, 3, 1), (**2**, 3, 1, 1)... and yield the result.
- Finally, we do the same with `first_element` = 3.

Answer (score 15):

A naive approach might be to take the set of the permutations:

```
list(set(it.permutations([1, 1, 1])))
# [(1, 1, 1)]
```

However, this technique wastefully computes replicate permutations and discards them.  A more efficient approach would be [`more_itertools.distinct_permutations`](https://more-itertools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#more_itertools.distinct_permutations), a [third-party tool](https://github.com/erikrose/more-itertools).

**Code**

```
import itertools as it

import more_itertools as mit


list(mit.distinct_permutations([1, 1, 1]))
# [(1, 1, 1)]
```

**Performance**

Using a larger iterable, we will compare the performances between the naive and third-party techniques.

```
iterable = [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
len(list(it.permutations(iterable)))
# 720

%timeit -n 10000 list(set(it.permutations(iterable)))
# 10000 loops, best of 3: 111 µs per loop

%timeit -n 10000 list(mit.distinct_permutations(iterable))
# 10000 loops, best of 3: 16.7 µs per loop
```

We see `more_itertools.distinct_permutations` is an order of magnitude faster.

---

**Details**

From the source, a recursion algorithm (as seen in the accepted answer) is used to compute distinct permutations, thereby obviating wasteful computations.  See the [source code](https://github.com/erikrose/more-itertools/blob/master/more_itertools/more.py#L500) for more details.

Comment: Upvoted. `list(mit.distinct_permutations([1]*12+[0]*12))` also turned out to be ~5.5 times faster than `list(multiset_permutations([1]*12+[0]*12))` from @Bill Bell's answer.

Answer (score 14):

You could try using set:

```
>>> list(itertools.permutations(set([1,1,2,2])))
[(1, 2), (2, 1)]
```

The call to set removed duplicates

Comment: He might need list(set(itertools.permutations([1,1,2,2])))

Comment: Or `list(itertools.permutations({1,1,2,2}))` in Python 3+ or Python 2.7, due to the existence of set literals. Though if he's not using literal values, he'd just be using `set()` anyway. And @ralu: look at the question again, filtering afterwards would be costly.

Comment: set(permutations(somelist)) != permutations(set(somelist))

Comment: the problem with this is that I need the output to have the length of the input. E.g. ``list(itertools.permutations([1, 1, 0, 'x']))`` but wihtout the duplicates where the ones are interchanged.

Comment: @ahojnnes: If that's a requirement, then you really do need to filter afterwards even if you don't want to. Which means `list(set(itertools.permutations([1,1,2,2])))` is what you'd need to use.

Comment: @JAB: hm, this takes a very long time for more than 12 values... what I actually want is something like ``itertools.product((0, 1, 'x'), repeat=X)`` but I need to process values with few 'x's first (sorted is not suitible because it's generating a list and using too much memory).

Answer (score 12):

This is my solution with 10 lines:

```
class Solution(object):
    def permute_unique(self, nums):
        perms = [[]]
        for n in nums:
            new_perm = []
            for perm in perms:
                for i in range(len(perm) + 1):
                    new_perm.append(perm[:i] + [n] + perm[i:])
                    # handle duplication
                    if i < len(perm) and perm[i] == n: break
            perms = new_perm
        return perms


if __name__ == '__main__':
    s = Solution()
    print s.permute_unique([1, 1, 1])
    print s.permute_unique([1, 2, 1])
    print s.permute_unique([1, 2, 3])
```

--- Result ----

```
[[1, 1, 1]]
[[1, 2, 1], [2, 1, 1], [1, 1, 2]]
[[3, 2, 1], [2, 3, 1], [2, 1, 3], [3, 1, 2], [1, 3, 2], [1, 2, 3]]
```

Comment: I like this solution

Comment: I'm glad you like this method

Comment: Hi @LittleRoys. I used a slightly modified version of your code for a [PR in `more-itertools`](https://github.com/erikrose/more-itertools/pull/208). Are you ok with that?

Comment: I'm curious, does the class add any value?  Why isn't this just a function?

Comment: @DonHatch Maybe only to provide additional place for `Solution` somewhere ;-) ? BTW the function itself works. In contrast to `more_itertools.distinct_permutations`, it returns a list instead of an iterable, and the results are not sorted.

Answer (score 4):

The best solution to this problem I have seen uses Knuth's "Algorithm L" (as noted previously by Gerrat in the comments to the original post):
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12836385/how-can-i-interleave-or-create-unique-permutations-of-two-stings-without-recurs/12837695

Some timings:

Sorting `[1]*12+[0]*12` (2,704,156 unique permutations):
Algorithm L → 2.43 s
Luke Rahne's solution → 8.56 s
`scipy.multiset_permutations()` → 16.8 s

Answer (score 3):

Here is a recursive solution to the problem.

```
def permutation(num_array):
    res=[]
    if len(num_array) <= 1:
        return [num_array]
    for num in set(num_array):
        temp_array = num_array.copy()
        temp_array.remove(num)
        res += [[num] + perm for perm in permutation(temp_array)]
    return res

arr=[1,2,2]
print(permutation(arr))
```

Answer (score 3):

To generate unique permutations of `["A","B","C","D"]` I use the following:

```
from itertools import combinations,chain

l = ["A","B","C","D"]
combs = (combinations(l, r) for r in range(1, len(l) + 1))
list_combinations = list(chain.from_iterable(combs))
```

Which generates:

```
[('A',),
 ('B',),
 ('C',),
 ('D',),
 ('A', 'B'),
 ('A', 'C'),
 ('A', 'D'),
 ('B', 'C'),
 ('B', 'D'),
 ('C', 'D'),
 ('A', 'B', 'C'),
 ('A', 'B', 'D'),
 ('A', 'C', 'D'),
 ('B', 'C', 'D'),
 ('A', 'B', 'C', 'D')]
```

Notice, duplicates are not created (e.g. items in combination with `D` are not generated, as they already exist).

**Example:** This can then be used in generating terms of higher or lower order for OLS models via data in a Pandas dataframe.

```
import statsmodels.formula.api as smf
import pandas as pd

# create some data
pd_dataframe = pd.Dataframe(somedata)
response_column = "Y"

# generate combinations of column/variable names
l = [col for col in pd_dataframe.columns if col!=response_column]
combs = (combinations(l, r) for r in range(1, len(l) + 1))
list_combinations = list(chain.from_iterable(combs))

# generate OLS input string
formula_base = '{} ~ '.format(response_column)
list_for_ols = [":".join(list(item)) for item in list_combinations]
string_for_ols = formula_base + ' + '.join(list_for_ols)
```

Creates...

```
Y ~ A + B + C + D + A:B + A:C + A:D + B:C + B:D + C:D + A:B:C + A:B:D + A:C:D + B:C:D + A:B:C:D'
```

Which can then be piped to your [OLS regression](https://www.statsmodels.org/stable/regression.html)

```
model = smf.ols(string_for_ols, pd_dataframe).fit()
model.summary()
```

Answer (score 2):

It sound like you are looking for itertools.combinations() [docs.python.org](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations)

```
list(itertools.combinations([1, 1, 1],3))
[(1, 1, 1)]
```

Comment: No, combinations would have the same problem.

Comment: only gives it in order, e.g [1, 2, 3] would produces [1, 2, 3] but not [3, 2, 1] or [2, 3, 1] etc

Answer (score 1):

Bumped into this question while looking for something myself !

Here's what I did:

```
def dont_repeat(x=[0,1,1,2]): # Pass a list
    from itertools import permutations as per
    uniq_set = set()
    for byt_grp in per(x, 4):
        if byt_grp not in uniq_set:
            yield byt_grp
            uniq_set.update([byt_grp])
    print uniq_set

for i in dont_repeat(): print i
(0, 1, 1, 2)
(0, 1, 2, 1)
(0, 2, 1, 1)
(1, 0, 1, 2)
(1, 0, 2, 1)
(1, 1, 0, 2)
(1, 1, 2, 0)
(1, 2, 0, 1)
(1, 2, 1, 0)
(2, 0, 1, 1)
(2, 1, 0, 1)
(2, 1, 1, 0)
set([(0, 1, 1, 2), (1, 0, 1, 2), (2, 1, 0, 1), (1, 2, 0, 1), (0, 1, 2, 1), (0, 2, 1, 1), (1, 1, 2, 0), (1, 2, 1, 0), (2, 1, 1, 0), (1, 0, 2, 1), (2, 0, 1, 1), (1, 1, 0, 2)])
```

Basically, make a set and keep adding to it. Better than making lists etc. that take too much memory..
Hope it helps the next person looking out :-) Comment out the set 'update' in the function to see the difference.

Comment: The `, 4` should be removed so it will work on things of any length.  Even with that fixed, this isn't a great solution.  For one thing it stores all the items in memory at once, defeating some of the advantages of a generator.  For another, it's still super inefficient in terms of time, in some cases where it should be instant.  Try `for i in dont_repeat([1]*20+[2]): print i`; it will take forever.

Answer (score 1):

You can make a function that uses `collections.Counter` to get unique items and their counts from the given sequence, and uses `itertools.combinations` to pick combinations of indices for each unique item in each recursive call, and map the indices back to a list when all indices are picked:

```
from collections import Counter
from itertools import combinations
def unique_permutations(seq):
    def index_permutations(counts, index_pool):
        if not counts:
            yield {}
            return
        (item, count), *rest = counts.items()
        rest = dict(rest)
        for indices in combinations(index_pool, count):
            mapping = dict.fromkeys(indices, item)
            for others in index_permutations(rest, index_pool.difference(indices)):
                yield {**mapping, **others}
    indices = set(range(len(seq)))
    for mapping in index_permutations(Counter(seq), indices):
        yield [mapping[i] for i in indices]
```

so that `[''.join(i) for i in unique_permutations('moon')]` returns:

```
['moon', 'mono', 'mnoo', 'omon', 'omno', 'nmoo', 'oomn', 'onmo', 'nomo', 'oonm', 'onom', 'noom']
```

Answer (score 1):

This is my attempt without resorting to set / dict, as a generator using recursion, but using string as input.  Output is also ordered in natural order:

```
def perm_helper(head: str, tail: str):
    if len(tail) == 0:
        yield head
    else:
        last_c = None
        for index, c in enumerate(tail):
            if last_c != c:
                last_c = c
                yield from perm_helper(
                    head + c, tail[:index] + tail[index + 1:]
                )


def perm_generator(word):
    yield from perm_helper("", sorted(word))
```

example:

```
from itertools import takewhile
word = "POOL"
list(takewhile(lambda w: w != word, (x for x in perm_generator(word))))
# output
# ['LOOP', 'LOPO', 'LPOO', 'OLOP', 'OLPO', 'OOLP', 'OOPL', 'OPLO', 'OPOL', 'PLOO', 'POLO']
```

Answer (score 1):

```
ans=[]
def fn(a, size): 
    if (size == 1): 
        if a.copy() not in ans:
            ans.append(a.copy())
            return

    for i in range(size): 
        fn(a,size-1); 
        if size&1: 
            a[0], a[size-1] = a[size-1],a[0] 
        else: 
            a[i], a[size-1] = a[size-1],a[i]
```

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/heaps-algorithm-for-generating-permutations/

Answer (score 0):

Came across this the other day while working on a problem of my own.  I like Luka Rahne's approach, but I thought that using the Counter class in the collections library seemed like a modest improvement.  Here's my code:

```
def unique_permutations(elements):
    "Returns a list of lists; each sublist is a unique permutations of elements."
    ctr = collections.Counter(elements)

    # Base case with one element: just return the element
    if len(ctr.keys())==1 and ctr[ctr.keys()[0]] == 1:
        return [[ctr.keys()[0]]]

    perms = []

    # For each counter key, find the unique permutations of the set with
    # one member of that key removed, and append the key to the front of
    # each of those permutations.
    for k in ctr.keys():
        ctr_k = ctr.copy()
        ctr_k[k] -= 1
        if ctr_k[k]==0: 
            ctr_k.pop(k)
        perms_k = [[k] + p for p in unique_permutations(ctr_k)]
        perms.extend(perms_k)

    return perms
```

This code returns each permutation as a list.  If you feed it a string, it'll give you a list of permutations where each one is a list of characters.  If you want the output as a list of strings instead (for example, if you're a terrible person and you want to abuse my code to help you cheat in Scrabble), just do the following:

```
[''.join(perm) for perm in unique_permutations('abunchofletters')]
```

Answer (score 0):

I came up with a very suitable implementation using itertools.product in this case (this is an implementation where you want all combinations

```
unique_perm_list = [''.join(p) for p in itertools.product(['0', '1'], repeat = X) if ''.join(p).count() == somenumber]
```

this is essentially a combination (n over k) with n = X and somenumber = k
itertools.product() iterates from k = 0 to k = X subsequent filtering with count ensures that just the permutations with the right number of ones are cast into a list. you can easily see that it works when you calculate n over k and compare it to the len(unique_perm_list)

Answer (score 0):

Adapted to remove recursion, use a dictionary and numba for high performance but not using yield/generator style so memory usage is not limited:

```
import numba

@numba.njit
def perm_unique_fast(elements): #memory usage too high for large permutations
    eset = set(elements)
    dictunique = dict()
    for i in eset: dictunique[i] = elements.count(i)
    result_list = numba.typed.List()
    u = len(elements)
    for _ in range(u): result_list.append(0)
    s = numba.typed.List()
    results = numba.typed.List()
    d = u
    while True:
        if d > 0:
            for i in dictunique:
                if dictunique[i] > 0: s.append((i, d - 1))
        i, d = s.pop()
        if d == -1:
            dictunique[i] += 1
            if len(s) == 0: break
            continue
        result_list[d] = i
        if d == 0: results.append(result_list[:])
        dictunique[i] -= 1
        s.append((i, -1))
    return results
```

```
import timeit
l = [2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5, 5, 6, 6]
%timeit list(perm_unique(l))
#377 ms ± 26 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

ltyp = numba.typed.List()
for x in l: ltyp.append(x)
%timeit perm_unique_fast(ltyp)
#293 ms ± 3.37 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

assert list(sorted(perm_unique(l))) == list(sorted([tuple(x) for x in perm_unique_fast(ltyp)]))
```

About 30% faster but still suffers a bit due to list copying and management.

Alternatively without numba but still without recursion and using a generator to avoid memory issues:

```
def perm_unique_fast_gen(elements):
    eset = set(elements)
    dictunique = dict()
    for i in eset: dictunique[i] = elements.count(i)
    result_list = list() #numba.typed.List()
    u = len(elements)
    for _ in range(u): result_list.append(0)
    s = list()
    d = u
    while True:
        if d > 0:
            for i in dictunique:
                if dictunique[i] > 0: s.append((i, d - 1))
        i, d = s.pop()
        if d == -1:
            dictunique[i] += 1
            if len(s) == 0: break
            continue
        result_list[d] = i
        if d == 0: yield result_list
        dictunique[i] -= 1
        s.append((i, -1))
```

Answer (score 0):

May be we can use set here to obtain unique permutations

```
import itertools
print('unique perms >> ', set(itertools.permutations(A)))
```

Answer (score -1):

What about

```
np.unique(itertools.permutations([1, 1, 1]))
```

The problem is the permutations are now rows of a Numpy array, thus using more memory, but you can cycle through them as before

```
perms = np.unique(itertools.permutations([1, 1, 1]))
for p in perms:
    print p
```