# Permutations with repetition in Python

Tags: python, algorithm, permutation

I want to iterate over all the vertices of an `n` dimensional cube of size 1. I know I could do that with `itertools.product` as follows:

```
>>> n = 3
>>> for j in it.product((0,1), repeat=n) :
...     print j
... 
(0, 0, 0)
(0, 0, 1)
(0, 1, 0)
(0, 1, 1)
(1, 0, 0)
(1, 0, 1)
(1, 1, 0)
(1, 1, 1)
```

But I need to treat differently each of the vertices, depending on the number of `1`s found in its coordinates, i.e. `(0, 1, 1)`, `(1, 0, 1)` and  `(1, 1, 0)` will all receive the same tratment, as they all have two `1`s. Rather than using the above iterator, and then counting the number of `1`s, I would like to generate the cartesian product ordered by number of `1`s, something along the lines of:

```
>>> for ones in xrange(n) :
...     for seq in magic_expression(ones, n) :
...         print ones, seq
... 
0 (0, 0, 0)
1 (0, 0, 1)
1 (0, 1, 0)
1 (1, 0, 0)
2 (0, 1, 1)
2 (1, 0, 1)
2 (1, 1, 0)
3 (1, 1, 1)
```

My high school math teacher would have called these something like **permutations of 2 elements taken `n` at a time, where the first element repeats `n - ones` times, and the second `ones` times**, and it is easy to show that there are `n! / ones! / (n - ones)!` of them.

According to [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation#Generation_in_lexicographic_order) I can generate them in lexicographical order with something like this:

```
def lexicographical(ones, n) :
    perm = [0] * (n - ones) + [1] * ones
    yield tuple(perm)
    while True :
        k = None
        for j in xrange(n - 1) :
            if perm[j] < perm[j + 1] :
                k = j
        if k is None :
            break
        l = k + 1
        for j in xrange(k + 2, n) :
            if perm[k] < perm[j] :
                l = j
        perm[k], perm[l] = perm[l], perm[k]
        perm[k+1:] = perm[-1:k:-1]
        yield tuple(perm)
```

But timing it, this only starts to pay-off against counting in the full cartesian product for `n >= 10`, and then only for `ones < 2`, which is not the typical use case. Is there an elegant way of speeding up my code above, perhaps with some powerful `itertools` voodoo, or using a different algorithm altogether? If it makes any difference, I couldn't care less about the ordering of the permutations produced. Or should I resign myself to counting?

---

***EDIT***

I did some timings on the proposed solutions. Consuming the vertices in the order `itertools.product` generates them an counting is always the fastest. But to have them generated ordered by number of ones, Eevee's solution of sorting the list is the fastest for `n <= 6`, and from then on Cam's solution is the fastest of the two.

I have accepted Cam's solution, because it is the one that better replied to what was being asked. But as far as what I am going to implement in my code, I am going to resign myself to counting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your use-case of 3d cubes, Eevee's solution is the correct one.

However for fun and to demonstrate the power of itertools, here's a linear-time solution that generalizes to higher dimensions:

```
from itertools import combinations

# n is the number of dimensions of the cube (3 for a 3d cube)
def generate_vertices(n):
    for number_of_ones in xrange(0, n + 1):
        for location_of_ones in combinations(xrange(0, n), number_of_ones):
            result = [0] * n
            for location in location_of_ones:
                result[location] = 1
            yield result

for vertex in generate_vertices(3):
    print vertex


# result:
# [0, 0, 0]
# [1, 0, 0]
# [0, 1, 0]
# [0, 0, 1]
# [1, 1, 0]
# [1, 0, 1]
# [0, 1, 1]
# [1, 1, 1]
```

Comment: Nice! This is the sort of thing I was looking for. Isn't the `set` operation unnecessary?

Comment: @Jaime: No because sets have constant time access, which is needed for the part below. However you raise a good point which is that that section's a bit verbose. I've updated it to be more clear and probably a little faster

Comment: for your reference here was my original solution: https://gist.github.com/4536013

Answer (score 5):

If you've written more than eight lines of code to generate eight constant values, something has gone wrong.

Short of just embedding the list I want, I'd do it the dumb way:

```
vertices = (
    (v.count(1), v)
    for v in itertools.product((0, 1), repeat=3)
)
for count, vertex in sorted(vertices):
    print vertex
```

Unless you're working with 1000-hypercubes, you shouldn't have any huge performance worries.

Answer (score 3):

An (inefficient) alternative method:

```
>>> ['{0:03b}'.format(x) for x in range(8)]
['000', '001', '010', '011', '100', '101', '110', '111']
```

Or as tuples:

```
>>> [tuple(int(j) for j in list('{0:03b}'.format(x))) for x in range(8)]

[(0, 0, 0),
 (0, 0, 1),
 (0, 1, 0),
 (0, 1, 1),
 (1, 0, 0),
 (1, 0, 1),
 (1, 1, 0),
 (1, 1, 1)]
```

Sorted by number of vertices:

```
>>> sorted(_, key=lambda x: sum(x))

[(0, 0, 0),
 (0, 0, 1),
 (0, 1, 0),
 (1, 0, 0),
 (0, 1, 1),
 (1, 0, 1),
 (1, 1, 0),
 (1, 1, 1)]
```

---

Or using itertools:

```
>>> sorted(itertools.product((0, 1), repeat=3), key=lambda x: sum(x))

[(0, 0, 0),
 (0, 0, 1),
 (0, 1, 0),
 (1, 0, 0),
 (0, 1, 1),
 (1, 0, 1),
 (1, 1, 0),
 (1, 1, 1)]
```

Answer (score 1):

It is not a bad idea to count depending on what you will do with the vertices because if you have to iterate over all of them doing something O(f(n)) is at least O(f(n)*2**n), sorting them is O(n*2**n). So it basically depends if f(n) majors n.

Aside from that here is a possible magic expression:

```
def magic_expression(ones, n):
    a = (0,) * (n - ones) + (1,) * ones
    previous = tuple()
    for p in itertools.permutations(a):
        if p > previous:
            previous = p
            yield p
```

With help from [permutations with unique values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6284396/permutations-with-unique-values).

This works because itertools.permutations yield sorted results. Note that a is initially sorted because zeros come first.

Comment: this does not solve the problem. it asks for a way to iterate over the vertices of a cube sorted by the number of ones - this does not do that.

Comment: although not the best solution this does what's expected from the magic_expression of the question, that when combined with `for ones in xrange(3): ...` will yield the expected output.

Comment: Oops! Indeed it does. Thanks for clarifying.

Answer (score 1):

Following is some code that runs faster (for medium `n`) and several times faster (for large `n`) than that of Cam or Eevee.  A time comparison follows.

```
def cornersjc (n):   # Re: jw code
    from itertools import product
    m = (n+1)/2
    k = n-m
    # produce list g of lists of tuples on k bits
    g = [[] for i in range(k+1)]
    for j in product((0,1), repeat=k):
        g[sum(j)].append(tuple(j))
    # produce list h of lists of tuples on m bits
    if k==m:
        h = g
    else:
        h = [[] for i in range(m+1)]
        for j in product((0,1), repeat=m):
            h[sum(j)].append(tuple(j))
    # Now deliver n-tuples in proper order
    for b in range(n+1):  # Deliver tuples with b bits set
        for lb in range(max(0, b-m), min(b+1,k+1)):
            for l in g[lb]:
                for r in h[b-lb]:
                    yield l+r
```

The timing results shown below are from a series of `%timeit` calls in ipython.  Each call was of a form like
`%timeit [x for x in cube1s.f(n)]`
with the names `cornersjc, cornerscc, cornersec, cornerses` in place of `f` (standing for my code, Cam's code, Eevee's code, and my version of Eevee's method) and a number in place of `n`.

```
n    cornersjc    cornerscc    cornersec    cornerses

5      40.3 us      45.1 us      36.4 us      25.2 us    
6      51.3 us      85.2 us      77.6 us      46.9 us    
7      87.8 us      163 us       156 us       88.4 us    
8     132 us       349 us       327 us       178 us    
9     250 us       701 us       688 us       376 us    
10    437 us      1.43 ms      1.45 ms       783 us
11    873 us      3 ms         3.26 ms      1.63 ms
12   1.87 ms      6.66 ms      8.34 ms      4.9 ms
```

Code for `cornersjc` was given above.  Code for `cornerscc`,    `cornersec`, and   `cornerses` is as follows.  These produce the same output as `cornersjc`, except that Cam's code produces a list of lists instead of a list of tuples, and within each bit-count group produces in reverse.

```
def cornerscc(n):   # Re: Cam's code
    from itertools import combinations
    for number_of_ones in xrange(0, n + 1):
        for location_of_ones in combinations(xrange(0, n), number_of_ones):
            result = [0] * n
            for location in location_of_ones:
                result[location] = 1
            yield result

def cornersec (n):   # Re:  Eevee's code
    from itertools import product
    vertices = ((v.count(1), v)
                for v in product((0, 1), repeat=n))
    for count, vertex in sorted(vertices):
        yield vertex

def cornerses (n):   # jw mod. of Eevee's code
    from itertools import product
    for vertex in sorted(product((0, 1), repeat=n), key=sum):
        yield vertex
```

Note, the last three lines of `cornersjc` can be replaced by

```
            for v in product(g[lb], h[b-lb]):
                yield v[0]+v[1]
```

which is cleaner but slower.  Note, if `yield v` is used instead of `yield v[0]+v[1]`, the code runs faster than `cornersjc` but (at `n=5`) produces pair-of-tuple results like ((1, 0), (1, 1, 0)); when  `yield v[0]+v[1]` is used, the code runs slower than `cornersjc` but  produces identical results, a list of tuples like (1, 0, 1, 1, 0).
An example timing follows, with `cornersjp` being the modified `cornersjc`.

```
In [93]: for n in range(5,13):
    %timeit [x for x in cube1s.cornersjp(n)]
   ....:     
10000 loops, best of 3: 49.3 us per loop
10000 loops, best of 3: 64.9 us per loop
10000 loops, best of 3: 117 us per loop
10000 loops, best of 3: 178 us per loop
1000 loops, best of 3: 351 us per loop
1000 loops, best of 3: 606 us per loop
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.28 ms per loop
100 loops, best of 3: 2.74 ms per loop
```