# All possible merges of lists in python

Tags: python, list, merge, permutation

I would like to get all the possible ways to merge 2 (or ideally n) lists in python, while maintaining each list's internal order - i.e. I would like to find some function all_merges that would behave like this:

```
a = all_merges([1,2],[3,4])
```

results in:

```
a = [
[1,2,3,4],
[1,3,2,4],
[1,3,4,2],
[3,1,2,4],
[3,1,4,2],
[3,4,1,2]   ]
```

(I hope this is all of them)

I cannot find simple, 'pythonic' way to do this - please help!

=====

Note:

I am considering something like this (written to be relatively readable):

```
from itertools import permutations
def all_merges(list1,list2):
    a = [1]*len(list1)
    b = [2]*len(list2)
    indexes = list(set(list(permutations(a+b))))
    lists = [[]]*3
    res = indexes # just for readability, will be overwriting indexes as we go along
    for perm in indexes:
        lists[1] = copy(list1)
        lists[2] = copy(list2)
        merge = perm
        for i in range(0,len(perm)):
            merge[j] = lists[perm[i]].pop(0)
    return res
```

however at the stage

```
list(set(list(permutations(a+b))
```

if the combined length of the lists is so much as 15 I get a huge amount of results from

```
permutations(a+b)
```

(15!, to be precise), whereas at most I will only really have 15choose7 (= 6435) different merges.

I realise a replacement to that line is provided here, as a function: [permutations with unique values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6284396/permutations-with-unique-values)
but by now this is getting messy and I want to see if there is a cleaner solution to my original problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Each possible merge corresponds directly to one of `(len(a) + len(b)) choose len(a)` ways to pick `len(a)` positions for the elements of `a` in the final list:

```
import itertools
def all_merges(a, b):
    # object guaranteed not to be in either input list
    sentinel = object()
    merged_length = len(a) + len(b)
    for a_positions in itertools.combinations(xrange(merged_length), len(a)):
        merged = [sentinel] * merged_length

        # Place the elements of a in their chosen positions.
        for pos, a_elem in zip(a_positions, a):
            merged[pos] = a_elem

        # Place the elements of b in the positions not taken.
        b_iter = iter(b)
        for pos in xrange(merged_length):
            if merged[pos] is sentinel:
                merged[pos] = next(b_iter)

        yield merged
```

This can be extended to more lists in several ways, such as by using some technique (perhaps [Algorithm L](http://guptamukul.blogspot.com/2009/12/understanding-algorithm-l_05.html)) to go through all ways to assign positions to list elements, or by applying the 2-way merge repeatedly.

Comment: This is great, thank you! 
For posterity, I'll note that I had to change xrange to range, and I got the desired result using list(all_merges(a,b))