# interleaving two strings, preserving order: functional style

Tags: haskell, functional-programming

In [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36260956/all-possible-ways-to-interleave-two-strings), the author brings up an interesting programming question: given two string, find possible 'interleaved' permutations of those that preserves order of original strings.

I generalized the problem to `n` strings instead of 2 in OP's case, and came up with:

```hs
-- charCandidate is a function that finds possible character from given strings.
-- input : list of strings
-- output : a list of tuple, whose first value holds a character 
-- and second value holds the rest of strings with that character removed
-- i.e ["ab", "cd"] -> [('a', ["b", "cd"])] ..

charCandidate xs = charCandidate' xs []
charCandidate' :: [String] -> [String] -> [(Char, [String])]
charCandidate' [] _ = []     
charCandidate' ([]:xs) prev = 
    charCandidate' xs prev
charCandidate' (x@(c:rest):xs) prev =
    (c, prev ++ [rest] ++ xs) : charCandidate' xs (x:prev)

interleavings :: [String] -> [String]
interleavings xs = interleavings' xs []    

-- interleavings is a function that repeatedly applies 'charCandidate' function, to consume
-- the tuple and build permutations.
-- stops looping if there is no more tuple from charCandidate.

interleavings' :: [String] -> String -> [String]
interleavings' xs prev = 
    let candidates = charCandidate xs
        in case candidates of
            [] -> [prev]
            _  -> concat . map (\(char, ys) -> interleavings' ys (prev ++ [char])) $ candidates

-- test case
input :: [String]
input = ["ab", "cd"]    
-- interleavings input == ["abcd","acbd","acdb","cabd","cadb","cdab"]
```

it works, however I'm quite concerned with the code:

1. it is ugly. no point-free!
2. explicit recursion and additional function argument `prev` to preserve states
3. using tuples as intermediate form

How can I rewrite the above program to be more "haskellic", concise, readable and more conforming to "functional programming"?

Comment: I wouldn't recommend pursuing point-free style too far.  It may be educational and even fun, but if taken beyond a certain point, point-free programming can make things less readable, not more...

Comment: Also, please avoid the likes of `(:) (...) $ ...` in favor of `(...):(...)`.  In the above case, you don't even need the second set of parens...

Comment: I haven't tested, but I suspect you meant to write `charCandidate'` everywhere you currently have `getCandidate`, and meant to write `charCandidate'` everywhere you currently have `charCandidate` in the five lines following the type declaration for `charCandidate'`.

Comment: @DanielWagner sorry, I've changed some names while copypasting from my editor and it seems I forgot to make my edit match with name-changes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I would write it this way. The main idea is to treat creating an interleaving as a nondeterministic process which chooses one of the input strings to start the interleaving and recurses.

Before we start, it will help to have a utility function that I have used countless times. It gives a convenient way to choose an element from a list and know which element it was. This is a bit like your `charCandidate'`, except that it operates on a single list at a time (and is consequently more widely applicable).

```
zippers :: [a] -> [([a], a, [a])]
zippers = go [] where
    go xs [] = []
    go xs (y:ys) = (xs, y, ys) : go (y:xs) ys
```

With that in hand, it is easy to make some non-deterministic choices using the list monad. Notionally, our `interleavings` function should probably have a type like `[NonEmpty a] -> [[a]]` which promises that each incoming string has at least one character in it, but the syntactic overhead of `NonEmpty` is too annoying for a simple exercise like this, so we'll just give wrong answers when this precondition is violated. You could also consider making this a helper function and filtering out empty lists from your top-level function before running this.

```
interleavings :: [[a]] -> [[a]]
interleavings [] = [[]]
interleavings xss = do
    (xssL, h:xs, xssR) <- zippers xss
    t <- interleavings ([xs | not (null xs)] ++ xssL ++ xssR)
    return (h:t)
```

You can see it go in ghci:

```
> interleavings ["abc", "123"]
["abc123","ab123c","ab12c3","ab1c23","a123bc","a12bc3","a12b3c","a1bc23","a1b23c","a1b2c3","123abc","12abc3","12ab3c","12a3bc","1abc23","1ab23c","1ab2c3","1a23bc","1a2bc3","1a2b3c"]
> interleavings ["a", "b", "c"]
["abc","acb","bac","bca","cba","cab"]
> permutations "abc" -- just for fun, to compare
["abc","bac","cba","bca","cab","acb"]
```

Comment: what is `[xs | hay xs]` ?

Comment: @thkang Ah, right, so: `[e1 | e2]` is a list that contains element `e1` if `e2` evaluates to `True` and an empty list if `e2` evaluates to `False`. So it's shorthand for `if hay xs then [xs] else []`. Cute, no? Anyway the purpose is to maintain the invariant that we pass only non-empty lists to `interleavings`.

Comment: thanks, that was the only part I couldn't understand - I've read about zippers but it's nice to see a real application here (I'm quite new to haskell).

Comment: For posterity: thkang's earlier question mentions `[xs | hay xs]`. This is because originally I had defined `hay = not . null`; but I decided it wasn't worth splitting out into its own function and inlined it, so the new spelling is `[xs | not (null xs)]`.

Comment: I've come up with an implementation that seems to be much faster when dealing with long lists. Could you possibly take a look and see if you have any suggestions (especially for making it prettier)?

Answer (score 2):

This is fastest implementation I've come up with so far. It interleaves a list of lists pairwise.

```hs
interleavings :: [[a]] -> [[a]]
interleavings = foldr (concatMap . interleave2) [[]]
```

This horribly ugly mess is the best way I could find to interleave two lists. It's intended to be asymptotically optimal (which I *believe* it is); it's not very pretty. The constant factors could be improved by using a special-purpose queue (such as the one used in `Data.List` to implement `inits`) rather than sequences, but I don't feel like including that much boilerplate.

```hs
{-# LANGUAGE BangPatterns #-}
import Data.Monoid
import Data.Foldable (toList)
import Data.Sequence (Seq, (|>))

interleave2 :: [a] -> [a] -> [[a]]
interleave2 xs ys = interleave2' mempty xs ys []

interleave2' :: Seq a -> [a] -> [a] -> [[a]] -> [[a]]
interleave2' !prefix xs ys rest =
  (toList prefix ++ xs ++ ys)
     : interleave2'' prefix xs ys rest

interleave2'' :: Seq a -> [a] -> [a] -> [[a]] -> [[a]]
interleave2'' !prefix [] _ = id
interleave2'' !prefix _ [] = id
interleave2'' !prefix xs@(x : xs') ys@(y : ys') =
  interleave2' (prefix |> y) xs ys' .
      interleave2'' (prefix |> x) xs' ys
```

Answer (score 1):

Using foldr over interleave2

```
interleave :: [[a]] -> [[a]]
interleave = foldr ((concat .) . map . iL2) [[]]  where 
   iL2 [] ys = [ys]
   iL2 xs [] = [xs]
   iL2 (x:xs) (y:ys) = map (x:) (iL2 xs (y:ys)) ++ map (y:) (iL2 (x:xs) ys)
```

Answer (score 0):

Another approach would be to use the list monad:

```
interleavings xs ys = interl xs ys ++ interl ys xs where
  interl [] ys = [ys]
  interl xs [] = [xs]
  interl xs ys = do
    i <- [1..(length xs)]
    let (h, t)  = splitAt i xs
    map (h ++) (interl ys t)
```

So the recursive part will alternate between the two lists, taking all from 1 to N elements from each list in turns and then produce all possible combinations of that. Fun use of the list monad.

Edit: Fixed bug causing duplicates

Edit: Answer to dfeuer. It turned out tricky to do code in the comment field. An example of solutions that do not use `length` could look something like:

```
interleavings xs ys = interl xs ys ++ interl ys xs where 
  interl [] ys = [ys]
  interl xs [] = [xs]
  interl xs ys = splits xs >>= \(h, t) -> map (h ++) (interl ys t)

splits [] = []
splits (x:xs) = ([x], xs) : map ((h, t) -> (x:h, t)) (splits xs)
```

The splits function feels a bit awkward. It could be replaced by use of `takeWhile` or `break` in combination with `splitAt`, but that solution ended up a bit awkward as well. Do you have any suggestions?

(I got rid of the do notation just to make it slightly shorter)

Comment: Can you see a way to avoid `length`? It's not really needed here.

Comment: You could lazily produce all possible ways to split the list and then draw elements from that. I tried one version but it did not make it more readable, and I am not sure it would be faster either.

Comment: Just realised that this solution is very similar to that of Daniel Wagner

Comment: Another option (better, I think) is to recognize that interleaving can be done pairwise.

Comment: Hm. Please elaborate

Answer (score 0):

Combining the best ideas from the existing answers and adding some of my own:

```
import Control.Monad

interleave [] ys = return ys
interleave xs [] = return xs
interleave (x : xs) (y : ys) =
  fmap (x :) (interleave xs (y : ys)) `mplus` fmap (y :) (interleave (x : xs) ys)

interleavings :: MonadPlus m => [[a]] -> m [a]
interleavings = foldM interleave []
```

This is not the fastest possible you can get, but it should be good in terms of general and simple.

Comment: It's pretty, and it was my original answer, but it has some performance problems. Left-nested `++` and lots of repeated `map` applications will make this slow.

Comment: Indeed. Such inefficiencies are dwarfed by the output size though so they are unlikely to matter much.

Comment: Edited the answer slightly so that `interleavings` works for any `MonadPlus` now. This means you can make it faster just by using a different monad!

Comment: Better, but the nested maps are still an issue, and you have to get to the end of the first list before you produce anything at all. I like your `mplus` idea, but I don't think it's sufficient.