# Combination of two lists while keeping the order

Tags: python, combinations, permutation, python-itertools

I'm trying to join two lists and output all possible combinations of the merged list that maintains the ordering of the original two lists. For example:

```
list_1 = [9,8]
list_2 = [2,1]

#output
combo= [9821,9281,2981,2918,2198,9218]
```

where in each element in the list "combo", **2** always comes before **1** and **9** always comes before **8**.

so far I've used permutations from itertools to do loop all possible permutations, but it is not fast enough.

Here's what I got:

```
from itertools import permutations
seq = [5, 9, 8, 2, 1]
plist = []
root = seq[0]
left = filter(lambda x: x > root, seq)
right =  filter(lambda x: x < root, seq)  

for pseq in permutations(seq[1:]):
    pseq = (root,) + pseq
    if list(filter(lambda x: x > root, pseq)) == left and list(filter(lambda x: x < root, pseq)) == right:
        plist.append(pseq)
print plist
```

Thanks!

Comment: You should routinely expect such a task to consist of: *"first,* combine the lists, *then,* sort the combined result.  In the *(most unusual)* case at bar, you should certainly require that the individual component lists each must be sorted.

Comment: The method you are using depends on a sort property, but the lists are not sorted.  How would it apply to [9,1] and [8,2]?  It fails there. I'll try to post a solution shortly.

Comment: Even when you going over all permutations, the logic seems a bit complex. You could use permutation.index(element) to check the position and yank out a permutation.

Comment: This problem is equivalent to [All possible ways to interleave two strings](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36260956/all-possible-ways-to-interleave-two-strings), just with different input containers (lists of integers instead of strings). Possible duplicate?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Give this a try:

```
import itertools

lst1 = ['a', 'b']
lst2 = [1, 2]

for locations in itertools.combinations(range(len(lst1) + len(lst2)), len(lst2)):
    result = lst1[:]
    for location, element in zip(locations, lst2):
        result.insert(location, element)
    print(''.join(map(str, result)))

# Output:
# 12ab
# 1a2b
# 1ab2
# a12b
# a1b2
# ab12
```

The way I think of the problem, you start with the first sequence (`ab` in this case), and then look for all the possible places you can insert the elements of the second sequence (in this case, a `1` and then a `2`).

The `itertools.combinations` call gives you those combinations. In the above example, it iterates through the positions `(0, 1)`, `(0, 2)`, `(0, 3)`, `(1, 2)`, `(1, 3)`, `(2, 3)`.

For each of those sets of coordinates, we just insert the elements from the second list at the specified indexes.

**UPDATE**

Here's a recursive solution that handles any number of lists, based on @Đặng Xuân Thành's suggestion in his answer:

```
import itertools

def in_order_combinations(*lists):
    lists = list(filter(len, lists))

    if len(lists) == 0:
        yield []

    for lst in lists:
        element = lst.pop()
        for combination in in_order_combinations(*lists):
            yield combination + [element]
        lst.append(element)

for combo in in_order_combinations(['a', 'b'], [1, 2]):
    print(''.join(map(str, combo)))
```

The basic idea is that, starting with `ab` and `12`, you know that all possible solutions will either end with `b` or `2`. The ones that end with `b` will all start with a solution for (`a`, `12`). The ones that end with `2` will all start with a solution for (`ab`, `1`).

The base case for the recursion is simply when there are no lists left. (Empty lists are pruned as we go.)

Comment: Wow that was quick! Thanks for explaining how you did it.

Answer (score 3):

It would be a bit cleaner if your output was a list of lists instead of concatenated digits, but it doesn't matter. Here's a simple recursive solution in python3 (but you can trivially convert it to python2).

```
def combine(xs, ys):
    if xs == []: return [ys]
    if ys == []: return [xs]
    x, *xs_tail = xs
    y, *ys_tail = ys
    return [ [x] + l for l in combine(xs_tail, ys) ] + \
           [ [y] + l for l in combine(ys_tail, xs) ]
```

This will return a list of lists:

```
>>> combine([9, 8], [2, 1])
[[9, 8, 2, 1], [9, 2, 1, 8], [9, 2, 8, 1], [2, 1, 9, 8], [2, 9, 8, 1], [2, 9, 1, 8]]
```

Here's how to convert it to your desired output:

```
def list_to_int(digits):
    return int(''.join(map(str, digits)))

def combine_flat(xs, ys):
    return [list_to_int(l) for l in combine(xs, ys)]
```

Answer (score 2):

A solution using a recursive generator (requires Python 3 for `yield from ...`):

```
def f(a,b,p=[]):
    if len(a)==0 or len(b)==0:
        yield p+a+b
    else:
        yield from f(a[1:],b,p+[a[0]])
        yield from f(a,b[1:],p+[b[0]])
```

at each step, you can pick the first character of `a` or the first character of `b`, and recursively build the rest of the list(s). if one of the two becomes empty, there are no more choice points.

```
>>> list(f([9,8],[2,1]))
[[9, 8, 2, 1], [9, 2, 8, 1], [9, 2, 1, 8], [2, 9, 8, 1], [2, 9, 1, 8], [2, 1, 9, 8]]
```

Update: starting from the above solution, here's an implementation that handles any number of lists:

```
def f(*args,p=[]):
    if any(len(arg)==0 for arg in args):
        yield p+[el for arg in args for el in arg]
    else:
        for i,arg in enumerate(args):
            args1=list(args)
            args1[i]=arg[1:]
            yield from f(*args1,p=p+[arg[0]])
```

Comment: I posted recursive solution, that might be easier to understand but definitely is slower. I think your solution is best in here, so it's not fair for you not to have a upvote ;) up to you!

Comment: I was going to comment about this too. Your solution is very clear, and especially if one knows a bit of Lisp/Haskell/Prolog might immediately understand it. On the other hand, one thing that I like about generators, is that if you only need the first k items, using generators you will have not wasted any CPU power in generating the other n-k items that you are not going to use.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know more about python but I have an idea may help.
The idea is using the recursive:
 To join two lists n & m items, we have two cases:

- Join two lists n-1 & m items, then put the n-th items at the end.
- Join two lists n & m-1 items, then put the m-th items at the end.

Use this recursive, you just need to handle the simplest case: join two lists with one of them is empty.
It will fast then using permutation.
Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

Long(ish) one-liner

```
from itertools import *
from copy import deepcopy

list({''.join(str(l.pop(0)) for l in deepcopy(p)) for p in permutations(chain(repeat(list_1, len(list_1)), repeat(list_2, len(list_2))))})
```

See my answer to the similar problem [All possible ways to interleave two strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36260956/all-possible-ways-to-interleave-two-strings/36264336#36264336) for an explanation.