# How to flatten out the yield when yielding a generator?

Tags: python, iterator, return, yield

I have this function `g()` my goal is to yield a result similar to `product()` but with constrained number of appearance for each group of characters. So in the code below instead of doing `product(a, repeat=3)` `g()` is supposed to yield all the combinations where characters from `a` appear 2 times and characters from `b` appear 1 time. Here is what I have :

```
from itertools import permutations, product

a='ABC'
b=['*', '%3A']
l=[a]*2+[b]

def g(list):
    for p in permutations(list):
        yield product(*p)


result=g(l)
```

So the problem I'm facing is that when I `yield` the result I got a nested iterator that is painful to use and when I use return it just returns the generator corresponding to only the first loop turn, just as if I did : `g()` only consisted of `def g(): return product(*next(permutations(list)))`.

Comment: Think about what you would do if you weren't writing a `g` generator, and you just wanted to call `some_function(x)` on every combination. Write that code, and then replace `some_function` with `yield`.

Comment: @snakecharmerb python 3, oh yes you're right there is `yield from` I totally forgot, I solved the problem using `c=chain(c,product(*p))` and returning c at the end, had the idea just after posting that.

Comment: I noticed that if I do `result=sorted(map(list, g(l)))` that `all(result[i] == result[i+1] for i in range(0, 6, 2))` is `True`.  In other words, it seems you get two identical sets of results.  Do you want that?

Comment: @StevenRumbalski you're right thanks for the observation, is there a way to avoid `permutations()` to generate identical lists in the same generator ?

Comment: If the current behavior is what you want, I wouldn't change anything.  Or am I misunderstanding?

Comment: @StevenRumbalski I mean you're right about that being a problem, I definitely don't want to iterate multiple times through the same elements for my main problem. It's due to the fact that `permutations()` is generating identical lists if fed with a list containing some identical elements. I wonder if you know a solution to avoid that.

Comment: See the answer to [permutations with unique values](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6284396/permutations-with-unique-values).

Comment: Or use `from sympy.utilities.iterables import multiset_permutations` which may be more efficient.

Comment: Or use [`more_itertools.distinct_permutations(iterable)`](https://more-itertools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#more_itertools.distinct_permutations).

Comment: @StevenRumbalski incredible, with every other solutions I was met with `unashable type list` but the sympy package worked like a charm, thanks a lot for your help !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are python 3.3 or later you can use [PEP 380: Syntax for Delegating to a Subgenerator](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.3.html#pep-380-syntax-for-delegating-to-a-subgenerator) ... just do `yield from`

```
from itertools import permutations, product

a='ABC'
b=['*', '%3A']
l=[a]*2+[b]

def g(list):
    for p in permutations(list):
        yield from product(*p)


result=g(l)
```

Comment: I forgot about yield from thanks for the tip this is useful