# all permutations of (b, c, a, ..., a) in a numpy array

Tags: python, numpy, permutation

For starters, lets consider two different float values `a` and `b` and an integer `d`. I would like to create a `numpy.array` that contain all permutations of

```
(b, a, a, ..., a)
```

where the length of the vector is `d+1`. For example, `d=2`, I would like to get

```
a = 3.14
b = 2.71
numpy.array([
    [b, a, a],
    [a, b, a],
    [a, a, b],
    ])
```

While this case could be quite easily generated by hand, more interesting to me are permutations of

```
(b, b, a, a, ..., a)
(b, c, a, a, ..., a)
(b, b, b, a, ..., a)
```

(where `c` is a float different from `a` and `b`).

The first one would start off as

```
numpy.array([
    [b, b, a, ..., a],
    [b, a, b, ..., a],
    ...
    [b, a, ..., a, b],
    [a, b, b, a, ..., a],
    ...
    ])
```

Any hints?

Comment: I don't get the logic. Do you have a concrete example, with numbers instead of variable names? Also, what did you try?

Comment: Why is it filled with `a` in the first example but with `b` and `a` in the second? Is there any "requirement" missing from the problem description?

Comment: The second one (with the `c` would need some explanation -- the first one is quite simple -- just create an array full of `a` and put `b` on the diagonal.

Comment: @EricDuminil I don't understand what's unclear. Would you like me to fill in `a=3.123123` and `b=5.1213`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [permutations with unique values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6284396/permutations-with-unique-values)

Comment: This question has already been answered here, with an efficient algorithm : https://stackoverflow.com/a/6285203/6419007 `set(itertools.permutations)` works in theory but is highly inefficient.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `itertools.permutations` for this task.

```
from itertools import permutations

a = [1.0, 2.0, 2.0]
perms = set(permutations(a))
```

Comment: Yeah Eric. I just missed that step. ```perms = set(permutations(a))```

Comment: Replacing the strings with floats works too, apparently.

Comment: Also, this solution is highly inefficient if there are many `a`s. With 1 `b` and 9 `a`s, you'd generate 3628800 permutations to only keep 10.