# How can I optimize my code to answer the path numbers I can go from A to B?

Tags: python, python-3.x, algorithm, list, optimization

I have just started coding with Python recently.Now I am trying to recognize how many ways I can move from A to B, whether there is any obstacles in my path or not.
For instance, I have such a table:

```
0 1 0 0 0
1 0 0 0 1
0 0 1 0 0
0 0 0 0 0
```

As usual, I intend to start from bottom left to reach top right(The zero in the last line and first column is the start and the zero in the first line and last column is the finish point). And I can pass through '0's but not '1's. **The output is the number of possible paths. In this example  the output is 5.**

I will be really pleased if you help me for a bigger table like this:

```
0 0 0 1 0 1 0
1 0 1 0 0 0 0
0 0 1 0 0 1 0
0 0 0 1 0 0 1
1 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 1 1 1
0 0 0 1 0 1 0
```

The answer here is 8.

Thanks for your replies. Other solutions are welcomed too.

Comment: Provide an example, please, of what the output should be in both cases.

Comment: @SteveJ thanks for your mention.
I have added the outputs of these two table.

Comment: Try reading up on depth-first search. That can help you out with your problem.

Comment: I am not a professional.
I will be happy if you can provide a link where I can know more about it.
@Sean Francis N. Ballais 9

Comment: Here's a [link](https://www.hackerearth.com/practice/algorithms/graphs/depth-first-search/tutorial/) to information about depth-first search.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to this answer:https://stackoverflow.com/a/48046575/8921005
My permutation faced with a huge problem which by help of this function I've overcome this problem.