# Unique permutations with repeating elements in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, math, permutation

Suppose we have the elements 0 and 1, which can occour more than once, something like `00 00 11`, `00 00 11 11` or `01 11` (split into groups of 2 for better readability).

I've already a function to generate all unique permutations:

```js
class UniqueElement {
  constructor(value, occurrences) {
    this.value = value;
    this.occurrences = occurrences;
  }
}

function permUnique(elements) {
  let set = new Set(elements);
  let listunique = Array.from(set).map((i) => new UniqueElement(i, elements.filter((el) => el === i).length));
  let u = elements.length;
  return permUniqueHelper(listunique, "0".repeat(u).split("").map((i) => parseInt(i)), u - 1);
}
function* permUniqueHelper(listunique, result_list, d) {
  if (d < 0) {
    yield [...result_list];
  } else {
    for (const i of listunique) {
      if (i.occurrences > 0) {
        result_list[d] = i.value;
        i.occurrences--;
        for (const g of permUniqueHelper(listunique, result_list, d - 1)) yield g;
        i.occurrences++;
      }
    }
  }
}

// call like:
// permUnique([0,0,1,1])
console.log(Array.from(permUnique([0,0,1,1])).join('\n'));
```

Translated into JavaScript from here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6285203/10362619

Now my intention is to use these generated permutations as indices for other objects. 
These are then used in code, where the order of these objects doesn't matter:

```
10 10
01 01
```

are the same in the end for example, or

```
01 20 12
02 10 21
10 21 02
12 01 20
...
```

for a base with `0`, `1` and `2` starting from `00 11 22`.

They are considered the same, because equal numbers are in the same position. Just switch two numbers (e.g. 0 with 1) and you'll get the other.

Again, all these examples are just split into groups of two for better readability. `00 11 22` means the same as `001122`, where each digit is a single element in the input array.

Is the fastest way to filter the elements afterwards after the permutations have been created or can this criteria be implemented in the function?

**Edit:** It is no requirement that it is a generator function that permutes the array

**Edit 2:** To make things even more clear: The first example I gave has the pattern `abab` where `a` can be either `0` or `1` and `b` is the opposite. The second example follows the pattern `abcabc` where `a`, `b` and `c` can all be either `0`, `1` or `2` (but not the same).

Comment: The thing about generator functions is that they're compose-able, and even composed, the iteration is still lazy, so "afterwards" is subjective. If you consume the generator inside another generator, you can yield the filtered values and still only iterate the set once.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts So you mean that I could wrap the whole thing inside another generator function that filters the permutations? I then just need a way of finding out if the pattern of the current permutation has already been returned...

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "pattern of current permutation has already been returned", but here's a small example: `function * foo (max, min = 0, step = 1) { for (let i = min; i < max; i += step) yield i } function * bar (iterable, filter = () => true) { for (const value of iterable) if (filter(value)) yield value } const odds = Array.from(bar(foo(10), v => v % 2));` You'll see that `odds` is `[1, 3, 5, 7, 9]`.

Comment: Yes, I've got that, thanks. I mean with "pattern of the current permutation" like the examples in the question: `10 10` has the same pattern as `01 01`.

Comment: Are the example things that are the same the same because they have the same numbers of 0s, 1s and 2s, or because equal numbers are in the same positions? i.e. would `011` be the same as `100` or `101`? I don’t understand the overall task here.

Comment: @Ry- I've updated the question to include why they are equal. I need a function that returns or generates the permutations of a given array (a multi-set), where some permutations are considered equal and therefore are not needed to be generated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After having an equality criteria between the different permutations, we need to establish a *canonical form* for each pattern (equality class). We will then try to only generate those.

In your case, where order of `1`s, `2`s and `3`s does not matter, we could decide that their respective first occurrences must be in the order `123`, and `2` cannot appear without `1` and `3` not without `2`. So whether the pattern is `aabcbc`, `aacbcb`, `bbacac`, …, or `ccbaba`, the only form that we want to generate is `112323`. Or when the pattern is `aaa`/`bbb`/`ccc` we only generate `111` but not `222` or `333`.

We can then write an algorithm which follows these rules for canonical forms:

```
function patterns(values, len) {
    function* recurse(list, used, depth) {
        if (depth == len) {
            yield list.slice();
        } else {
            for (let j=0; j<used; j++) { // only put already used values at this position
                list[depth] = values[j];
                yield* recurse(list, used, depth+1);
            }
            if (used < values.length) { // or the single next unused value
                list[depth] = values[used];
                yield* recurse(list, used+1, depth+1); // which is counted as used here
            }
        }
    }
    return recurse([], 0, 0);
}
```

This simply generates all combinations of a certain length from the distinct `values`, but you can use the same approach in your algorithm that generates permutations from a certain amount of non-unique values. It does get a bit more complicated though: the canonical form `121` cannot be achieved if we only have the values `122` available, but the pattern `212` still should be generated. We need to adjust our rule so that the ordering requirement is only amongst elements of the same number of occurrences. So we have to keep different `used` counts for them.

```
function permutationPatterns(elements) {
    const len = elements.length;
    const unique = new Map(elements.map(el => [el, {value: el, occurrences: 0}]));
    let max = 0;
    for (const el of elements) {
        const o = unique.get(el);
        max = Math.max(max, ++o.occurrences);
    }
    const byOccurrences = Array.from({length: max+1}, () => ({elements: [], used: 0}));
    for (const o of unique.values()) {
        byOccurrences[o.occurrences].elements.push(o);
    }

    function* generate(list, depth) {
        if (depth == len) {
            yield list.slice();
        } else {
            for (const options of byOccurrences) {
                options.used++;
                for (const option of options.elements.slice(0, options.used)) {
                    if (option.occurrences == 0) continue;
                    option.occurrences--;
                    list[depth] = option.value;
                    yield* generate(list, depth+1);
                    option.occurrences++;
                }
                options.used--;
            }
        }
    }
    return generate([], 0);
}
```

Comment: The last bit of code throws an error: _TypeError: Cannot read property 'elements' of undefined_.

At the line `byOccurrences[o.occurrences].elements.push(o);` I can't find the bug, because I can't figure out, what the `byOccurrences` should contain...

Comment: Ah, thought I'd fixed that already - the array needs to be one longer than the maximum index.

Comment: Thanks. Your code is fast as hell. I just need some more time to understand how it works, because I've some troubles with the recursion.

Answer (score 1):

If `12` and `21` are the same, like `10` and `01` are the same after all, then don't create all of them in the first place. The key idea here is to have a *canonical form* for each of the values, which could e.g. be that the digits are sorted ascending. So you'd only have the values `00`, `01`, `02`, `11`, `12` and `22`.

If the order in the sequence doesn't matter either, then you shouldn't be generating permutations. Again, choose a canonical form for the sequences.

You can then easily generate only ascending forms, and use the same generator once for your parts and once for the whole sequence:

```
function* generate(values, len) {
    if (len == 0)
        yield [];
    else
        for (const [i, val] of values.entries())
            for (const rest of generate(values.slice(i), len-1))
                yield [val, ...rest];
}

const duos = Array.from(generate([0, 1, 2], 2), x => x.join(""));
for (const x of generate(duos, 3))
    console.log(x.join(" "))
```

Comment: Thanks, but I think that you missunderstood my question. I'm generating from a fixed array its permutations, but I want to filter some permutations out as they have the same pattern as other permutations. I've updated my question to clarify this.

Comment: Sorry, I was really confused by the grouping and the phrase "*order of these objects doesn't matter*". Talking about `abc` *patterns* makes it clear, thanks. I'll add another answer.

Answer (score 0):

I've now wrapped the generator function inside a filter generator function as [@PatrickRoberts](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1541563/patrick-roberts) suggested in the comments of the question.

```js
class UniqueElement {
 constructor(value, occurrences) {
  this.value = value;
  this.occurrences = occurrences;
 }
}

function uniquePermutations(elements) {
 let set = new Set(elements);
 let listunique = Array.from(set).map((i) => new UniqueElement(i, elements.filter((el) => el === i).length));
 let u = elements.length;
 return uniquePermutationsHelper(listunique, "0".repeat(u).split("").map((i) => parseInt(i)), u - 1);
}
function* uniquePermutationsHelper(listunique, result_list, d) {
 if (d < 0) {
  yield [...result_list];
 } else {
  for (const i of listunique) {
   if (i.occurrences > 0) {
    result_list[d] = i.value;
    i.occurrences--;
    for (const g of uniquePermutationsHelper(listunique, result_list, d - 1)) yield g;
    i.occurrences++;
   }
  }
 }
}
function* uniquePermutationPatterns(elements) {
 let patterns = [];
 for (const perm of uniquePermutations(elements)) {
  // contains all unique elements in the order they appear. call patternVars.indexOf(element) and use its index for the patterns array
  let patternVars = Array.from(new Set(perm));

  let pattern = perm.map((p) => patternVars.indexOf(p));
    // convert the pattern to a number to avoid comparing array references and use the faster number comparison than the slower string comparison
  pattern = parseInt(pattern.join(""), patternVars.length);
  if (!patterns.length || !patterns.includes(pattern)) {
   patterns.push(pattern);
   yield perm;
  }
 }
}

let elements = [0,0,1,1];
let all = [...uniquePermutations(elements)];
let filtered = [...uniquePermutationPatterns(elements)];

console.log(`all permutations: (${all.length})`);
console.log(all.map((i) => i.join("")).join("\n"));
console.log(`\nfiltered permutations: (${filtered.length})`);
console.log(filtered.map((i) => i.join("")).join("\n"));
```

But that is about 3.2 times slower than simply generating all permutations. Which doesn't matter in my case. I only tested the performance for the array of elements `[0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2]` and that only a few times (less than 10)