# Find the largest and next-largest number remaining from a list

Tags: python, list, recursion

I have three lists: `word`, `occurrence`, and `alphabet` :

```py
occurrence = [2, 1, 3, 10] # but can be initialized differently
k = len(occurrence)
alphabet = [range(k)]
N = sum(occurrence)
word = [0]*N # initially
```

`word` is a list that will contain a certain combination of values pulled from `alphabet`, as decided by `occurrence`. In the example above, `word` must contain two `0`, one `1`, three `2`, and ten `3` in some combination.  `alphabet` can be used to index `occurrence`.

I have an algorithm ([see List-Fixed-Content by Sawada](https://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/82247950.pdf)) that recursively adds/removes "letters" in `alphabet` to/from `word`, decrementing the value in the corresponding index of `occurrence` when a letter is added, and incrementing that same value when a letter is removed.

The algorithm starts at the highest letter (`3` when first initialized in this case) where the corresponding index in `occurrence` is still greater than zero, then as the algorithm proceeds, goes to the NEXT highest letter that is still greater than zero.

I am currently handling this by removing a `letter` when its occurrence reaches 0, via `word.remove(letter)`, then adding it back in the correct position using `word.insert(i,letter)` when its occurrence increases again. This makes both finding the maximum value in the `alphabet` stepping down alphabet very easy.

The full code as requested:

```py
occurrence = [2, 5, 3, 5] # example occurrence
k = len(occurrence)
alphabet = [range(k)]
N = sum(occurrence)
word = [0]*N

def algorithm(t, p):
    if t > N:
        if N % p == 0:
            yield word.copy()     
    else:
        letter = max(alphabet)
        i = len(alphabet)-1
        while letter >= word[t-p-1]:
            word[t-1] = letter
            occurrence[letter] -= 1
            if not occurrence[letter]: # <<<<
                i_removed = remove(letter)
            if letter == word[t-p-1]:
                yield from algorithm(t+1, p)
            else:
                yield from algorithm(t+1, t)
            if not occurrence[letter]: # <<<<
                add(i_removed, letter)
            occurrence[letter] += 1
            i -= 1
            letter = get(i) # <<<<

def remove(letter):
    i = alphabet.index(letter)
    alphabet.remove(letter)
    return i

def add(i, letter):
    alphabet.insert(i,letter)

def get(i):
    if i < 0:
        return -1
    else:
        return alphabet[i]

def execute()
    yield from algorithm(1, 1)

# Example usage of function
print(list(execute()))
```

I've found this to be VERY slow, and I suspect it's because of `list.insert`. What is a better way of finding the highest and next-highest letters of `alphabet` whose corresponding values in `occurrence` are non-zero, without adding and removing letters from `alphabet`?

Something like assigning the lists as numpy arrays and the following code?

```py
...
letter = max(alphabet[occurrence > 0])
while letter >= limit: # some limit
    ...
    while True:   # <<<< replaces remove(), add(), and get()
        letter -= 1
        if letter < 0 or occurrence[letter] > 0:
            break
```

Comment: I haven't read your whole question, but from a skim, it looks like this code is working but not fast. So this would be a better question for [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com).

Comment: Where is your exit condition in the reccurence? From what i can see it starts with some value `t` then you loop  and use `words[t]` then `recursive_function(t+1)`. At some point `words[t]`will throw `IndexError` :|

Comment: Also Im not sure what is trying to be accomplished here.. do you want an `occurence = [2,1,3,10]` to result in `word = [0,0,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3]`? Because there are way easier ways to accomplish that :)

Comment: Or maybe you want `word = [3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,2,2,2,0,0,1]`?

Comment: @wjandrea should I delete this and repost to Code Review, then?

Comment: @Artog `recursive_function` will return a limited set of any `word` that contains any combination of the letters in `occurrence`, as specified by a `condition`.

Comment: @Rek You don't need to, but try checking out Code Review's [How to Ask](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask), [On topic](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic), and [Off topic](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask) pages to see if your question would be well-received there.

Comment: Running your code yields an empty list for me. Can you give an example result, f.ex. with the given preconditions in your post?

Comment: @Artog, I've added the full code

Comment: From what i could gather the function yields all unique permutations by value, i.e. `occurence = [2]` gives `[[0,0]]` but `occurence = [1,1]` gives `[[0,1],[1,0]]`. You can maybe take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6284396/permutations-with-unique-values#6285203