# Python itertools permutations without repetitions

Tags: python, permutation, python-itertools, combinatorics

I have a string show the step going in m x n grid like this problem:
https://leetcode.com/problems/unique-paths/

```
step = 'DDRR'
```

D mean go Down and R mean go to Right
I want to show permutations without replacement, and i found the itertools built-in on Python.But it's say:

> Elements are treated as unique based on their position, not on their value. So if the input elements are unique, there will be no repeat values.

So that when I using itertools.permutation(step,4), it's contain many replications.

```
>>> itertools.permutations(step,4)
('D', 'D', 'R', 'R')
('D', 'R', 'D', 'R')
('D', 'R', 'R', 'D')
('D', 'R', 'D', 'R')
('D', 'R', 'R', 'D')
('D', 'D', 'R', 'R')
('D', 'D', 'R', 'R')
('D', 'R', 'D', 'R')
('D', 'R', 'R', 'D')
('D', 'R', 'D', 'R')
('D', 'R', 'R', 'D')
('R', 'D', 'D', 'R')
('R', 'D', 'R', 'D')
('R', 'D', 'D', 'R')
('R', 'D', 'R', 'D')
('R', 'R', 'D', 'D')
('R', 'R', 'D', 'D')
('R', 'D', 'D', 'R')
('R', 'D', 'R', 'D')
('R', 'D', 'D', 'R')
('R', 'D', 'R', 'D')
('R', 'R', 'D', 'D')
('R', 'R', 'D', 'D')
```

I want something like:

```
('R', 'D', 'R', 'D')
('R', 'D', 'D', 'R')
('D', 'R', 'R', 'D')
('D', 'D', 'R', 'R')
('D', 'R', 'D', 'R')
('R', 'R', 'D', 'D')
```

I found some answer using **set(itertools.permutations(step,4))**, but because apply set() method, the itertools.permutation() method still calculate all possibilities. Is there anyway to avoid it, or **is there any built-in function can do permutation without repetitions in Python**?

Comment: im getting empty list using `itertools.permutations(step,4)`, maybe you meant `step = list('DDRR')`

Comment: Have you tried `itertools.combinations()`?

Comment: @zamir sorry, I edited my question, step is string not list

Comment: @Daniel I tried combinations, combinations_with_replacement, permutations and product also, but I can't get exactly what I want

Comment: My suspicion is that any algorithm to calculate the permutations wihout repetition will be no more efficient (maybe less efficient) than the itertools and set method you mention in your question, so probably not worth worrying over unless you are going to be using much longer strings.

Comment: @SimonN How "much longer"? For `DDDDDRRRRR` there are already 3.6 million permutations but only 252 different ones, so a reasonable method producing only the latter shouldn't have trouble being faster.

Comment: So you want to compute the number of distinct combinations of arranging exactly (m-1) `D` symbols and (n-1) `R`, or equivalently n `R` symbols with (m-1) bars `|` between them. (You don't need to compute the actual combinations, and for m,n up to 100 that would be prohibitive). The number of ways is given by the well-known [Stars-and-Bars formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics))

Comment: Tagged [tag:combinatorics]

Comment: @SimonN: that's totally incorrect, remember that C(n,k) is of the order of O(2^n), so you will blow out memory and CPU very quickly for non-toy values of n. [Remember the identity that [sum(C(n,k)) over k] = 2^n]

Comment: @smci yeah, that exactly what I want, but I want to know the way that we can do it easily (in coding) because I think it's a common problem.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [permutations with unique values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6284396/permutations-with-unique-values)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To get the answer you need, you could use [multiset_permutations](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/utilities/iterables.html)

```
>>> from sympy.utilities.iterables import multiset_permutations
>>> from pprint import pprint
>>> pprint(list(multiset_permutations(['D','D','R','R'])))
[['D', 'D', 'R', 'R'],
 ['D', 'R', 'D', 'R'],
 ['D', 'R', 'R', 'D'],
 ['R', 'D', 'D', 'R'],
 ['R', 'D', 'R', 'D'],
 ['R', 'R', 'D', 'D']]
```

To get just the total number, use factorial of number of items divided by the product of factorials for the count of each unique item. Here there are 2 D's and 2 R's

```
>>> from math import factorial
>>> factorial(4)//(factorial(2)*factorial(2))
6
```

Answer (score 3):

It's a terribly inefficient solution anyway. Just compute the number directly:

```
math.comb(m + n - 2, m - 1)
```

Comment: Note that `math.comb` is only available in Python 3.8+.

Comment: @blhsing Yes, and LeetCode runs 3.8.1.

Answer (score 2):

The leetcode problem only asks about the number of unique paths, not a list of unique paths, so to calculate the number you only need to use the combination formula of `C(n, k) = n! / (k! x (n - k)!)` to find the number of positions where `D`s (or `R`s) can be placed out of all positions:

```
from math import factorial

def f(m, n):
    return factorial(m + n - 2) / factorial(m - 1) / factorial(n - 1)
```

so that `f(3, 2)` returns: `3`

and that `f(7, 3)` returns: `28`

On the other hand, if you're interested in producing a list of unique paths, you can use `itertools.combinations` to do the same as above; that is, to find the positions where `D`s (or `R`s) can be placed out of all positions:

```
from itertools import combinations
def f(m, n):
    for positions in map(set, combinations(range(m + n - 2), m - 1)):
        yield ''.join('DR'[i in positions] for i in range(m + n - 2))
```

so that:

```
print(*f(7, 3), sep='\n')
```

outputs:

```
RRRRRRDD
RRRRRDRD
RRRRRDDR
RRRRDRRD
RRRRDRDR
RRRRDDRR
RRRDRRRD
RRRDRRDR
RRRDRDRR
RRRDDRRR
RRDRRRRD
RRDRRRDR
RRDRRDRR
RRDRDRRR
RRDDRRRR
RDRRRRRD
RDRRRRDR
RDRRRDRR
RDRRDRRR
RDRDRRRR
RDDRRRRR
DRRRRRRD
DRRRRRDR
DRRRRDRR
DRRRDRRR
DRRDRRRR
DRDRRRRR
DDRRRRRR
```

Answer (score -2):

Try using itertools.combinationss(step,4) instead of itertools.permutations(step,4)

Comment: itertools.combinationss(step,4) will return only ('D', 'D', 'R', 'R')

Comment: use this then, itertools.combinations_with_replacement(step,4)

Comment: I tried combinations, combinations_with_replacement, permutations and product also, but I can't get exactly what I want

Comment: No. `itertools.permutations` enumerates all the permutations (with tons of duplicates), but it's overkill.