# Generating all possibles combinations of values from a list of single values

Tags: python, combinatorics

Basically, I want to generate truth table list of values using Python.
For instance, if I have the following values: [0, 1], I want the following list to be generated:

[(0, 0), (0, 1), (1, 0), (1, 1)]

If I want my table to have three inputs, then the following list should be generated:

[(0, 0, 1), (0, 1, 0), (0, 0, 1), (0, 1, 1), (1, 0, 1), (1, 1, 0), (1, 0, 1), (1, 1, 1)]

So:

- All permutations should be generated
- No duplicate permutation in the list

Right now my solution is the following but I find it heavy:

```
from itertools import permutations

number_of_inputs = 3
set_of_values = [0, 1]
list_of_permutations = list(dict.fromkeys(list(permutations(set_of_values  * number_of_inputs, number_of_inputs))))
```

Do you have a better solution ? Such as a one-liner function call

Comment: Your solution is a one liner?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python itertools permutations without repetitions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60252053/python-itertools-permutations-without-repetitions)

Comment: `list_of_permutations = list(dict.fromkeys(list(permutations([0, 1]  * 3, 3))))` - half joking

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems like `product` is enough:

```py
number_of_inputs = 3
set_of_values = [0, 1]
list_of_permutations = itertools.product(set_of_values, repeat=3)
print(*list_of_permutations)
# (0, 0, 0) (0, 0, 1) (0, 1, 0) (0, 1, 1) (1, 0, 0) (1, 0, 1) (1, 1, 0) (1, 1, 1)
```

Comment: Seems legit ! :)

Answer (score 0):

does this work?

```py
from itertools import permutations

number_of_inputs = 3
set_of_values = [0, 1]
result = set(permutations(set_of_values  * number_of_inputs, number_of_inputs)
```