# Duplicates in list of permutations

Tags: python, algorithm, permutation, python-itertools

I am using the `permutations` function from the `itertools` library to print a list of permutations for a string.  In this case, it is `baca`.  However, the output list has duplicates of each element element.  Here it is:

```
['aabc', 'aabc', 'aacb', 'aacb', 'abac', 'abac', 'abca', 'abca', 'acab', 'acab', 'acba', 'acba', 'baac', 'baac', 'baca', 'baca', 'bcaa', 'bcaa', 'caab', 'caab', 'caba', 'caba', 'cbaa', 'cbaa']
```

Here is my code.  It's pretty straight forward.  I don't see anything in my code that would produce this behavior.

```
from itertools import permutations

def rearrangeWord(word):
    p = [''.join(i) for i in permutations(word) ]
    print(sorted(p))

rearrangeWord('baca')
```

Comment: I think this is happening because you have two `a`s in your string `baca`. If you want to only have one of each letter, use `permutations(set(word))` instead.

Comment: @EdWard But what that does is that it prints strings where each letter occurs only once.  I want to have permutations where every letter occurs as many times as they exist.

Comment: as there are 2 'a' in your string it is obvious you will get duplicates, see https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/distinct-permutations-string-set-2/

Comment: From documentation on itertools.product: "Elements are treated as unique based on their position, not on their value. So if the input elements are unique, there will be no repeat values in each permutation."

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6284396/permutations-with-unique-values

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[multiset_permutations](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/utilities/iterables.html) can find the permutations with multiple items.

```
>>> from sympy.utilities.iterables import multiset_permutations
>>> s = 'baca'


>>> for item in multiset_permutations(s):
    print(item)


['a', 'a', 'b', 'c']
['a', 'a', 'c', 'b']
['a', 'b', 'a', 'c']
['a', 'b', 'c', 'a']
['a', 'c', 'a', 'b']
['a', 'c', 'b', 'a']
['b', 'a', 'a', 'c']
['b', 'a', 'c', 'a']
['b', 'c', 'a', 'a']
['c', 'a', 'a', 'b']
['c', 'a', 'b', 'a']
['c', 'b', 'a', 'a']
```

Answer (score 2):

You are duplicating all 'aa' permutations.

```py
print(sorted(set(p)))
```

Comment: You don't need to call `list()`, `sorted` can sort any iterable.

Answer (score 1):

If you sort the word first (which is much cheaper), you don't need to sort afterwards:

```
>>> [*dict.fromkeys(map(''.join, permutations(sorted('baca'))))]
['aabc', 'aacb', 'abac', 'abca', 'acab', 'acba', 'baac', 'baca', 'bcaa', 'caab', 'caba', 'cbaa']
```

Answer (score 0):

This solved my problem:

`print(sorted(dict.fromkeys(p)))`

Now this is the output:

`['aabc', 'aacb', 'abac', 'abca', 'acab', 'acba', 'baac', 'baca', 'bcaa', 'caab', 'caba', 'cbaa']`