# Get all possible permutations of lists from a single list without duplicates

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to get all permutations of a list. So `[2, 2, 1]` would out put a generator with outputs `(2, 2, 1), (2, 1, 2), (1, 2, 2)`. I have tried a few ways of doing this but none have worked. For example, `itertools.product` does not work. For example, when I use `itertools.product`, the output is `(1, 1, 1), (1, 1, 2), (1, 2, 1), (1, 2, 2), (2, 1, 1), (2, 1, 2), (2, 2, 1), (2, 2, 2)`. `itertools.product` somehow gets three 1's in some of the lists even though I only inputted one 1. Is there any way to achieve what I want **completely in a generator without generating duplicates**?

Comment: You are looking for "permutations", not "combinations".

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to generate all permutations of a list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/104420/how-to-generate-all-permutations-of-a-list)

Comment: permutations alone would generate some duplicates, but combined with set() it gives what OP wants.

Comment: Well then https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6284396/permutations-with-unique-values

Comment: I'm looking for something that does this without generating duplicates without the need for `set` so I can keep it in a generator

Answer (score 0):

From what I can understand, you want to print the possible permutations that you can make with these numbers. If that's what you want then you can use permutations

Here is a code to illustrate it

```
from itertools import permutations


permutation = permutations([2, 2, 1],3)
output = []
for i in list(permutation):
    if i not in output:
        output.append(i)
        
print(output)
```

Comment: This creates duplicates, I want a way to do that without duplicates completely inside a generator (without using `set`, etc.)

Comment: Just updated my answer. Verify if that's what you are looking for

Comment: This answer is impractical for big lists, since it saves all of the values in a list which is very slow, at some point it'll just refuse to run

Answer (score 0):

You can use `numpy.roll` to shift the `1` between the indices. Do it in a function that yields the results to create generator object

```
import numpy as np

def roll(lst):
    for _ in range(len(lst)):
        lst = np.roll(lst, -1)
        yield tuple(lst)

lst = roll([2, 2, 1])
print(lst) # <generator object roll at 0x000001E1D915AAC0>
print(list(lst)) # [(2, 1, 2), (1, 2, 2), (2, 2, 1)]
```

Comment: try to `roll([2,2,2])`,got 3 duplicate `(2,2,2)`