# Get all possible order combinations in python

Tags: python, combinations

I have a list of 1 and 2, e.g. [2, 1, 1, 1] I need to get all possible combinations:

```
[[2, 1, 1, 1], 
[1, 2, 1, 1], 
[1, 1, 2, 1],
[1, 1, 1, 2]]
```

I tried to use itertools' product, however, it return the same result (e.g. [2, 1, 1, 1]) multiple times, and it is inefficient when input is bigger.
Is there some build in function for something like this?

Comment: I understand that it returns ones on different positions, is it possible to get around this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get all possible combinations of a list’s elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/464864/how-to-get-all-possible-combinations-of-a-list-s-elements)

Comment: You want [(unique) `permutations`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6284396/1639625), not `combinations` or`product`.

Comment: [multiset_permutations](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/utilities/iterables.html?highlight=multiset_permutations#sympy.utilities.iterables.multiset_permutations) gives the non-repeating permutations

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What you are looking for is permutations:

```py
>>> import itertools
>>> a = [2, 1, 1, 1]
>>> list(set(itertools.permutations(a)))
[(1, 1, 1, 2), (1, 1, 2, 1), (2, 1, 1, 1), (1, 2, 1, 1)]
```

Comment: `list(set(itertools.permutations(a)))` it will work too.

Comment: @Sabil True, updated

Comment: This is a very inefficient approach. Check out `multiset_permutations` from `sympy`.