# Powersets in Python using itertools

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-itertools

I'm trying to create a powerset in Python 3.  I found a reference to the `itertools`
 module, and I've used the powerset code provided on that page.  The problem:  the code returns a reference to an `itertools.chain` object, whereas I want access to the elements in the powerset.  My question: how to accomplish this?

Many thanks in advance for your insights.

Comment: related: [what's a good way to combinate through a set?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1482308/4279)

Comment: @BruceM, is it necessarily to use `itertools`?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

`itertools` functions return [*iterators*](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-iterator), objects that produce results lazily, on demand.

You could either loop over the object with a `for` loop, or turn the result into a list by calling `list()` on it:

```
from itertools import chain, combinations

def powerset(iterable):
    "powerset([1,2,3]) --> () (1,) (2,) (3,) (1,2) (1,3) (2,3) (1,2,3)"
    s = list(iterable)
    return chain.from_iterable(combinations(s, r) for r in range(len(s)+1))

for result in powerset([1, 2, 3]):
    print(result)

results = list(powerset([1, 2, 3]))
print(results)
```

You can also store the object in a variable and use the [`next()` function](http://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#next) to get results from the iterator one by one.

Answer (score 4):

Here's a solution using a generator:

```
from itertools import combinations

def all_combos(s):
    n = len(s)
    for r in range(1, n+1):
        for combo in combinations(s, r):
            yield combo
```

Comment: Thank you. I have stolen your answer with some modifications. Power sets, at least as defined math, include the empty set, so your `range` should start at 0. And power sets should treat any duplicated input element as just occurring once.

See https://github.com/jpgoldberg/powerset-generator for a package I'm developing based on your answer.

Answer (score 2):

Allen Downey's answer is what I would use, except I would replace the range with
`range(n+1)` since the empty set is considered an element of the power set.

This code can easily be rewritten as a one liner:

```
(combo for r in range(len(s) + 1) for combo in combinations(s, r))
```

Your choice whether to surround it with `()` for an iterator or `[]` for a list.