# How to store same value in two variables while independently changing them both in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, iterable-unpacking

I am trying to create a recursive function that returns the set of all non-empty subset of `[1,2,3,...,n]` numbers.

Here is my code:

```
def subsets(n):
    if n == 2:
        return ([1], [2], [1, 2])
    else:
        previous = subsets(n - 1)
        temp = previous
        result = ()
        for set in previous:
            set += [n]
            result += (set,)
        return temp + ([n],) + result
```

this doesn't work as `temp` stores the value of `previous` after it has been modified. Simply changing it to-

```
previous = subsets(n - 1)
temp = subsets(n - 1)
```

works but is obviously not a very efficient solution. I have also tried-

```
previous,temp = subsets(n - 1)
```

but this raises a "too many values to unpack" error. What do I do?

Comment: For `previous,temp = subsets(n - 1)` to work, `subsets` has to return two values, but it does not.

Comment: See [Powersets in Python using itertools](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18035595/674039)

Comment: i changed the return to a tuple of two exact same values but it only worked for subsets(3) when doing subsets(4) it gives back the same "too many values to unpack" error

Comment: As a quick fix you could use `temp = copy.deepcopy(previous)`.

Comment: Or even better: don't change `set` in place. Leaving complaints about shadowing builtin names to one side, try `set = set + [n]` in the loop.

Comment: thanks a ton paul! Both your answers work perfectly. I had no idea doing 
x=x+n is different from x+=n

Answer (score 1):

I want to point out that returning all subsets is something you can accomplish efficiently with `itertools`.

```
import itertools

def subsets(n):
    for x in range(1, n + 1):
        yield from itertools.combinations(range(1, n + 1), x)

print(*subsets(3))  # (1,) (2,) (3,) (1, 2) (1, 3) (2, 3) (1, 2, 3)
```

This returns a generator which will save a lot of memory since a power set grows exponentially.

Comment: This is the way to go!

Answer (score 0):

Since you're returning a tuple, Python return its reference. That's why when you change `previous`, `temp` changes as well.

To store them independently, you may use the slice operator:

```
previous = subsets(n - 1)
temp = previous[:]
```

Using [:] will copy `previous` content to `temp` instead of assigning `previous` reference to `temp`.

---

EDIT:

When you have some nesting inside your data structure, you would have to use a deepcopy:

```
import copy # at the top of your script

previous = subsets(n - 1)
temp = copy.deepcopy(previous)
```

Thanks to @Paul Panzer for pointing that out in the comments.

Comment: A shallow copy as created by slicing is not enough here. You need a deep copy.

Comment: doesn't work, it returns the exact same output as temp = previous

Comment: As @PaulPanzer pointed out, you'd need a deep copy. I've edited my answer to reflect that.

Answer (score 0):

What you need is a **deep** copy of `previous`, not just another reference `(temp = previous)` nor a shadow copy (`temp = previous[:]`).

```
previous = ([1],)
temp = previous[:]
myset = previous[0]
myset += [2]
print(previous)  # ([1, 2],) 
print(previous)  # ([1, 2],)
```

What you can do:

```
for set in previous:
    set = list(set)  # make a copy
    set += [n]
    result += (set,)
```

Answer (score 0):

The minimal change to you code would probably be to not modify `set` with `set += ([n], )`, but to create a new tuple with `set + ([n], )`. `temp` is unused then and can be removed. Full code:

```
def subsets(n):
    if n == 2:
        return ([1], [2], [1, 2])
    else:
        previous = subsets(n - 1)
        result = ()
        for set in previous:
            result += (set + [n],)
        return previous + ([n],) + result
```

Because `result += ...` creates a new tuple each time, this is not efficient and should be replaced by a generator expression:

```
def subsets(n):
    if n == 2:
        return ([1], [2], [1, 2])
    else:
        previous = subsets(n - 1)
        return previous + ([n],) + tuple(set + [n] for set in previous)
```