# Setting a range as an argument in itertools.permutations

Tags: python

I want to print all permutations of length 1-4 for the following list `[1,2,3,4]`

I know I could just set up a for-loop and pass in the for-loop index as an argument, but I was trying to get the following code to work:

```
import itertools
nums = [1,2,3,4]
perms = itertools.permutations(nums,range(1,4))
print(list(perms))
```

The hope was that the argument `range(1,4)` would run the intertools.permutations(nums) on string lengths 1, 2, 3 and 4.

Any ideas if it is possible to do this using the itertools notation?

Would it also be possible to print the case for length = 1 as:
`(1), (2), (3), (4)`
not 
`(1,), (2,), (3,), (4,)`

Comment: I believe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18035595/powersets-in-python-using-itertools) is what you're looking for.

Comment: A set of permutations is not the same as the power set of a set.

Answer (score 2):

Chain together 4 calls of `permutations`:

```
from itertools import chain, permutations

nums = [1,2,3,4]
perms = list(chain.from_iterable(permutations(nums, i) for i in range(1,5)))
print(perms)
```

If you want to print the 1-tuples as individual values, you'll need to handle that separately:

```
for t in perms:
    if len(t) == 1:
        print("(t[0])")
    else:
        print(t)
```

That's if you are concerned about the appearance of the tuple. If you truly want a non-tuple value, you'll need to extract the value separately, and keep in mind that `1` and `(1)` are the *exact* same value.

```
perms = list(nums,  # permutations(nums, 1) == nums
             chain.from_iterable(permutations(nums, i) for i in range(2,5)))
```

Comment: Is there a way to change (1,) to (1).... Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can also write it as a generator expression:

```
perms = (it for i in range(1, 4) for it in itertools.permutations(nums,i))
```