# python all combinations of subsets of a string

Tags: python, subset

I need all combinations of subsets of a string. In addition, a subset of length 1 can only be followed by a subset with length > 1. E.g. for string `4824` the result should be:

```
 [ [4, 824], [4, 82, 4], [48, 24], [482, 4], [4824] ]
```

So far I managed to retrieve all possible subsets with:

```
    length = len(number)
    ss = []
    for i in xrange(length):
        for j in xrange(i,length):
            ss.append(number[i:j + 1])
```

which gives me:

```
  ['4', '48', '482', '4824', '8', '82', '824', '2', '24', '4']
```

But I don't know how to combine those now.

Comment: Maybe it can help you [List Comprehension](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions)

Comment: By subset you mean a substring?

Comment: I think you are interested in [power sets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1482308/whats-a-good-way-to-combinate-through-a-set)

Comment: If you were successful in combine the elements then you would have some thing like : `[['4', '48', '482', '4824'], ['8', '82', '824'], ['2', '24'], ['4']]`

Comment: And what do I do with that then? The ouput should  be `[ [4, 824], [4, 82, 4], [48, 24], [482, 4], [4824] ]`

Comment: Is this some kind of weird variance on a power set? :)

Comment: "a subset of length 1 can only be followed by a subset with length > 1" How does `[4, 82, 4]` fit that rule? Or did you mean "immediately followed"?

Comment: This isn't about power sets. I don't know the proper terminology, but [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26791259/read-all-possible-sequential-substrings-in-python) is definitely related, and some of the answers given there could be refined for the additional requirement of *"subset of length 1 can only be followed by a subset with length > 1"*.

Comment: @wasp256 what would be expected output for 5-char string, eg. `abcde`?

Comment: Also related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4904430/find-all-list-permutations-of-a-string-in-python

Comment: Yeah sadly I've lost the plot with this question; it isn't clear what the OP is trying to do or the expected output and really what it all means :)

Comment: `[4, 8, 24]` why no ?

Comment: @JoseRicardoBustosM. "a subset of length 1 can only be followed by a subset with length > 1"

Comment: @skolsuper i post a answer, based it ... I hope is correct

Comment: @JoseRicardoBustosM. Upvoted already. I started something similar but didn't bother to tidy up the edge cases when I saw tobias' answer posted already. I agree with yours, I think it's better as a generator, and without resorting to sets.

Comment: @skolsuper thanks, i fixing my code .... "a subset of length 1 can only be followed by a subset with length > 1" ..... XD .... I had not read

Answer (score 9, accepted):

First, write a function for generating *all* the partitions of the string:

```
def partitions(s):
    if s:
        for i in range(1, len(s) + 1):
            for p in partitions(s[i:]):
                yield [s[:i]] + p
    else:
        yield []
```

This iterates all the possible first segments (one character, two characters, etc.) and combines those with all the partitions for the respective remainder of the string.

```
>>> list(partitions("4824"))
[['4', '8', '2', '4'], ['4', '8', '24'], ['4', '82', '4'], ['4', '824'], ['48', '2', '4'], ['48', '24'], ['482', '4'], ['4824']]
```

Now, you can just filter those that match your condition, i.e. those that have no two consecutive substrings of length one.

```
>>> [p for p in partitions("4824") if not any(len(x) == len(y) == 1 for x, y in zip(p, p[1:]))]
[['4', '82', '4'], ['4', '824'], ['48', '24'], ['482', '4'], ['4824']]
```

Here, `zip(p, p[1:])` is a common recipe for iterating over all pairs of consecutive items.

---

Update: Actually, incorporating your constraint directly into the `partition` function is not that hard, either. Just keep track of the last segment and set the minimum length accordingly.

```
def partitions(s, minLength=1):
    if len(s) >= minLength:
        for i in range(minLength, len(s) + 1):
            for p in partitions(s[i:], 1 if i > 1 else 2):
                yield [s[:i]] + p
    elif not s:
        yield []
```

Demo:

```
>>> print list(partitions("4824"))
[['4', '82', '4'], ['4', '824'], ['48', '24'], ['482', '4'], ['4824']]
```

Comment: This is inefficient for longer strings, since you are generating a lot of partitions that will be filtered.

Comment: @chepner Agreed. Added another algorithm doing the filtering while generating solutions.

Answer (score 2):

would be interesting to see more test cases, the following algorithm does what you say:

```
s="4824"

def partitions(s):
  yield [s]
  if(len(s)>2):
    for i in range(len(s)-1, 0, -1):
      for g in partitions(s[i:]):
        out = [s[:i]] + g
        if not any([len(out[i]) == len(out[i+1]) and len(out[i])==1 for i in range(len(out)-1)]):
          yield out

list(partitions(s))
```

you get:

```
[['4824'], ['482', '4'], ['48', '24'], ['4', '824'], ['4', '82', '4']]
```

**explanation**

I based on the following algorithm:

```
s="4824"

def partitions_original(s):
  #yield original string
  yield [s]
  if(len(s)>2):
    for i in range(len(s)-1, 0, -1):
      #divide string in two parts
      #iteration 1: a="482", b="4"
      #iteration 2: a="48", b="24"
      #iteration 3: a="4", b="824"
      a = s[:i]
      b = s[i:]
      #recursive call of b
      for g in partitions_original(b):
        #iteration 1: b="4", g=[['4']]
        #iteration 2: b="24", g=[['24']]
        #iteration 3: b="824", g=[['824'], ['82', '4'], ['8', '24']]
        yield [a] + g

list(partitions_original(s))
```

you get:

```
[['4824'], ['482', '4'], ['48', '24'], ['4', '824'], 
['4', '82', '4'], ['4', '8', '24']]
```

the problem is `['4', '8', '24']` ..... then I must add `if` to code, because *"a subset of length 1 can only be followed by a subset with length > 1"*

`[len(out[i]) == len(out[i+1]) and len(out[i])==1 for i in range(len(out)-1)]` return for `['4', '8', '24']` -> `[True, False]` .... `any` Return True if any element of the iterable is true

**NOTE**

also it can be used:

`if all([len(out[i]) != len(out[i+1]) or len(out[i])!=1 for i in range(len(out)-1)]):`

Answer (score 0):

What I am doing here is to get all the possible split position of the string and eliminate the last one.

for example, in some string with 5 numbers "12345" for ex., there is 4 possible position to split the string, call it `possibility = (0,0,0,0),(1,0,1,0)`... with `(0,0,1,0) mean (don't separate 1 and 2345,don't separate 12 and 345,separate 123 and 45,don't separate 1234 and 5)` so you can get all possibilities while your condition is verified since we eliminate the (1,1,1,1) case.

```py
import itertools
from math import factorial
from itertools import product

def get_comb(string):
    L = len(string_)
    combinisation = []

    for possibility in product([0,1], repeat=len(string_)-1):
        s = []
        indexes = [i for i in range(len(string_)-1) if list(possibility)[i]!=0]
        if sum(indexes) != 0:
            if sum(indexes) != len(string_)-1:
                for index in indexes:
                    s.append(string_[:index+1])
                s.append(string_[indexes[-1:][0]+1:])
                combinisation.append(s)
            else:
                combinisation.append(string_)
    return combinisation



string_ = '4824'
print "%s combinations:"%string_
print get_comb(string_)



string_ = '478952'
print "%s combinations:"%string_
print get_comb(string_)



string_ = '1234'
print "%s combinations:"%string_
print get_comb(string_)


>> 
4824 combinations:
[['482', '4'], ['48', '24'], '4824', ['4', '482', '4'], ['4', '48', '24'], '4824
']
478952 combinations:

[['47895', '2'], ['4789', '52'], ['4789', '47895', '2'], ['478', '952'], ['478',
 '47895', '2'], '478952', ['478', '4789', '47895', '2'], ['47', '8952'], '478952
', ['47', '4789', '52'], ['47', '4789', '47895', '2'], ['47', '478', '952'], ['4
7', '478', '47895', '2'], ['47', '478', '4789', '52'], ['47', '478', '4789', '47
895', '2'], ['4', '47895', '2'], ['4', '4789', '52'], ['4', '4789', '47895', '2'
], ['4', '478', '952'], ['4', '478', '47895', '2'], '478952', ['4', '478', '4789
', '47895', '2'], ['4', '47', '8952'], '478952', ['4', '47', '4789', '52'], ['4'
, '47', '4789', '47895', '2'], ['4', '47', '478', '952'], ['4', '47', '478', '47
895', '2'], ['4', '47', '478', '4789', '52'], ['4', '47', '478', '4789', '47895'
, '2']]

1234 combinations:

[['123', '4'], ['12', '34'], '1234', ['1', '123', '4'], ['1', '12', '34'], '1234
']
```

Comment: There seem to be some duplicate characters in your combinations, e.g. `['4', '482', '4']`. Also, I'd suggest being more consistent with the data types in the list, i.e. use `['4824']` instead of `'4824'`

Answer (score 0):

A normal code can be written like:

```
s=raw_input('enter the string:')
word=[]
for i in range(len(s)):
    for j in range(i,len(s)):
        word.append(s[i:j+1])

print word
print 'no of possible combinations:',len(word)
```

And output:
enter the string:
4824
['4', '48', '482', '4824', '8', '82', '824', '2', '24', '4']
no of possible combinations:10