# Add the empty set to a family of sets in a frozenset in python

Tags: python, set, frozenset

Suppose I generate a frozenset with

```
A = frozenset(frozenset([element]) for element in [1,2,3])
```

And I have the empty set

```
E = frozenset(frozenset())
```

Now I want to have the union of both sets:

```
U = A | E
```

This gives me

```
frozenset({frozenset({2}), frozenset({3}), frozenset({1})})
```

this assumes, that a frozenset, containing an empty frozenset is itself empty. However, I'd like to have

```
frozenset({frozenset({}), frozenset({2}), frozenset({3}), frozenset({1})})
```

So, I'd like to add the empty set explicitly to the set. This is, for example, necessary in my opinion when constructing a power set?

So: Is a family of sets that only contains the empty set itself empty? Is there a way, in Python, to explicitly include an empty set into a family of sets using the variable types `set` and `frozenset`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`E` is an empty set, with no elements:

```
>>> frozenset(frozenset())
frozenset()
```

That's because the argument to `fronenset()` is an *iterable of values to add*. `frozenset()` is an empty iterable, so nothing is added.

If you expected `E` to be a set with one element, you need to pass in an iterable with one element; use `{...}` set notation, or a single element tuple `(...,)`, or a list `[...]`:

```
>>> frozenset({frozenset()})  # pass in a set() with one element.
frozenset({frozenset()})
```

Now you get your expected output:

```
>>> A = frozenset(frozenset([element]) for element in [1,2,3])
>>> E = frozenset({frozenset()})
>>> A | E
frozenset({frozenset({3}), frozenset({2}), frozenset({1}), frozenset()})
```

Comment: Nice. That solves it. Thanks! I will accept when I can :D