# Lists in the python

Tags: python, list

1. We have to accept a list and find the `subsequent` from the list such that number in `subsequence` are in increasing order.
2. Find `sum` of each `subsequence`
3. `return maximum sum`

For example

```
Input=[1, 4,2]
```

Possible subsequence will be `[1][4][2][1,4][1,2]`
Here `[4,2]` will not come as `4` is greater.  And order should not change.  Means first position elements if it comes  in sublist it should be first

Sum of each subsequence will be  `1,4,2,5,3`
Output  will be `5`.

What will be your logic to solve it?

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow.com.
Please learn how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: You give us the logic and we try to help you. Where is your effort? Show us at least the minimum.

Comment: Ok.  Thank you.  I will remember those things while posting questions next time.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `itertools.combinations` and `itertools.chain` to do this easily

```
>>> from itertools import combinations, chain
>>> Input=[1, 4,2]
>>> max(map(sum, (filter(lambda x: sorted(x) == list(x), chain(*[combinations(Input, i) for i in range(1, len(Input)+1)])))))
5
```

**Explanation**

```
>>> possibilities = chain(*[combinations(Input, i) for i in range(1, len(Input)+1)])
>>> filtered_possibilities = filter(lambda x: sorted(x) == list(x), possibilities)
>>> sum_of_each_possibility = map(sum, filtered_possibilities)
>>> max_sum = max(sum_of_each_possibility)
>>> print (max_sum)
5
```

Comment: What if 2 numbers are same in the list? It will add both.  Here suppose [45,  78,22, 42,12,3,78].   The code you have explained  will print 201  it will take 45,78,78.   What if i dont want to add repetitive elements?

Comment: If the elements in `Input` are unique, each element in `possibilities` wont have the same numbers. So you would never `sum` same element again
If the elements in `Input` are not unique, make it unique by calling `Input = list(set(Input))`

Answer (score 0):

You can break down the question into three steps:

1) Find the power_set(all sub lists) of list.

2) Filter out unwanted list (list with decreasing order).

3) Find the max sum.

Step1:

```
def powerset(s):
    x = len(s)
    res=[]
    for i in range(1 << x):
        res.append([s[j] for j in range(x) if (i & (1 << j))])
    return res

lst=[1,4,2]
res=powerset(lst)
```

Step 2&3:

```
def max_sub(lsts):
    max_out=0
    def helper(lsts): #Step2: to filter out decreasing lists.
        if lsts==[]:
            return False
        else:
            for i in range(len(lsts)-1):
                if lsts[i]>lsts[i+1]:
                    return False
        return True
    filtered_lst=list(filter(lambda x:helper(x),lsts))
    for lst in filtered_lst:
        max_out=max(max_out,sum(lst))    #step3: Find out the max sub list sum.
    return max_out
print(max_sub(res))
```

Result:

```
5
```

Answer (score 0):

Drako already mentioned, that this is not free coding service. Show some effort yourself and tell us, what you already tried and how it didn't work. also provide output to help us analyze the problem. I'll help anyway; also welcome to StackOverflow.

What you are looking for is a "power set". An exhaustive set `M` of sets `s`, where each `s` is a subset of `M` and there is in fact no subset of `M` which is not already contained in a `s`. As sets are unordered by definition, you don't have to care about duplicates because of different ordering. Looking at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1482308/whats-a-good-way-to-combinate-through-a-set)

There is a nice answer to get the power set of a given set. Assuming your input list/set/iterable is `i`, you can use the following code to get the power set list.

```
from itertools import chain, combinations

def get_power_set(i):
    i.sort()    # Sorted input --> sorted output
    ps_iterable = chain.from_iterable(combinations(i, r) for r in range(len(i)+1))
    return list(ps_iterable)

def get_highest_sum(input_list):
    maximum = 0
    for s in input_list:
        sum_of_set = sum(s)
        if sum_of_set > maximum:
            maximum = sum_of_set
    return maximum

i = [1,2,3]     # Assign your input list here

power_set = get_power_set(i)
highest_sum = get_highest_sum(power_set)

print(power_set)
# >>> [(), (1,), (2,), (3,), (1, 2), (1, 3), (2, 3), (1, 2, 3)]
print("Highest sum is {}".format(highest_sum))
# >>> 6
```

Comment: You are not fulfilling his first requirement.

Comment: The subsets are tuples which are implicitly ordered in python. Also `combinations` produced an incrementing series in my test, just as desired. Did I miss something?

Comment: I did and added the expected output to my answer. Code was executed exactly like in the code block. Let me know if something is missing or incorrect.

Edit: I noticed that the resulting tuples of same size may be misordered, if the input is. Editing my answer to sort the input before calculating the power set.

Comment: I noticed the error and edited my answer. Sorting the input array now. Thanks for pointing that out @Marcus.Aurelianus.