# Python Difference Lambda Function and Normal Function

Tags: python, dictionary, lambda

Hi I am trying to find all possible substrings within a string

For example, if

`string = 'abc'`

I would like output to be

`['', 'a', 'b', 'ab', 'c', 'ac', 'bc', 'abc']`

This is a solution that works from

[Getting all combinations of a string and its substrings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51538192/getting-all-combinations-of-a-string-and-its-substrings)
(thank you @davidlowryduda)

```
def subs(string, ret=['']):
    if len(string) == 0:
        return ret
    head = string[0]
    tail = string[1:]
    ret = ret + list(map(lambda x: x+head, ret))   #this is the line I have problem with
    return subs(tail, ret)
```

and this is my code (I am trying not to use map or lambda function)

```
def addhead (ret, head):
        for i in ret:
            i += str(head)
        return ret

def subs2(string, ret=['']):
    if len(string) == 0:
        return ret
    head = string[0]
    tail = string[1:]
    ret = ret + addhead(ret,head)    #this is the line that I changed
    return subs(tail, ret)
```

However the output is now

```
['', '', 'b', 'b', 'c', 'c', 'bc', 'bc']
```

Does anyone knows what went wrong?

Thank you!

Comment: Could you use `itertools.combinations` here? eg: `output = [''.join(el) for n in range(len(string) + 1) for el in itertools.combinations(string, n)]`...

Comment: Your code looks like it's calling the old function: `return subs(...)` Is that a typo?

Comment: Hi Mark! Nope it wasnt a typo I was doing a recursive function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be

```
def addhead(ret, head):
    results = []

    for i in ret:
        results.append( i + str(head) )

    return results
```

You have to create new list with results and then return this list

---

Rest is the same - if you only uses `return subs2(...)` instead of `return subs(...)`

---

Full code:

```
def addhead(ret, head):
    results = []
    for i in ret:
        results.append(i + head)
    return results

def subs2(string, ret=['']):
    if len(string) == 0:
        return ret
    head = string[0]
    tail = string[1:]
    ret = ret + addhead(ret, head)
    return subs2(tail, ret)

print(subs2('abc'))
```