# create your own number system using python

Tags: python

I am making a small program that guesses a password.

I am making this program just for the purpose of learning, I want to improve my python skills by making a program that have a real meaning.

for example:

```
using_characts = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz" # I have other characters in my alphabetic system
```

What I want to do is something like this:

```
for char in myCharacters:
    print(char)
    for char_1 in myCharacters:
        print(char + char_1)
        for char_2 in myCharacters:
            print(char + char_1 + char_2)
            ...etc
```

which makes this method non dynamic, and hard in the same time.
the output should be something like this:

```
a

b

c

d

e

f

..etc

aa

ab

ac

..etc

ba

bb

bc

..etc
```

Comment: You want to generate all the combination of all length ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Making all possible combinations of a list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8371887/making-all-possible-combinations-of-a-list)

Comment: Yes, and the length maybe changed later

Comment: @azro, I haven't used itertools module before, it's for lists? I am trying to make my method work using a string, I'm not using lists in my program

Comment: This one is useful too: [Getting all combinations of a string and its substrings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51538192/getting-all-combinations-of-a-string-and-its-substrings)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Getting all combinations of a string and its substrings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51538192/getting-all-combinations-of-a-string-and-its-substrings)

Comment: @azro and it's not a good Idea to place all the possible values in the list, the possible values are nearly endless which makes the program slow using this algorithm

Comment: no I don't want the output to be a list, I want it to be a string

Comment: making the output a list, and then testing which value from the list are equal to correct the password (for example) will make the program 99x slower

Comment: I've just add an answer tell me how that is ok regarding your post ;)

Comment: You can use generators if you want to test possible passwords one by one and once you find the right password just stop. The key is yield keyword. :)

Comment: It's like a bitcoin miner lol finding the hash :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`itertools.product`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) but you should really limit yourself with a small number. Generating cartesian product for higher numbers can take really long time:

```
from itertools import chain, product
chars = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
limit = 2
for perm in chain.from_iterable(product(chars, repeat=i) for i in range(1, limit+1)):
    print("".join(perm))
```

```
a
b
c
.
.
.
aa
ab
ac
.
.
.
zy
zz
```

Answer (score 1):

Here you go, this will work. Let me know if you want me to explain any part.

```
import itertools

using_characts = "abc"

for str_length in range(1,len(using_characts)+1):
    for q in itertools.product(using_characts,repeat=str_length):
        print("".join(q))
```

Answer (score 1):

So, the other answers have given you code that will probably work, but I wanted to explain a general approach. This algorithm uses a stack to keep track of the next things that need to be generated, and continues generating until it reaches the maximum length that you've specified.

```py
from collections import deque
from typing import Deque, Iterator, Optional


def generate_next_strings(chars: str, base: str = "") -> Iterator[str]:
    # This function appends each letter of a given alphabet to the given base.
    # At its first run, it will generate all the single-length letters of the
    # alphabet, since the default base is the empty string.
    for c in chars:
        yield f"{base}{c}"


def generate_all_strings(chars: str, maxlen: Optional[int] = None) -> Iterator[str]:
    # We "seed" the stack with a generator. This generator will produce all the
    # single-length letters of the alphabet, as noted above.
    stack: Deque[Iterator[str]] = deque([generate_next_strings(chars)])

    # While there are still items (generators) in the stack...
    while stack:
        # ...pop the next one off for processing.
        next_strings: Iterator[str] = stack.popleft()

        # Take each item from the generator that we popped off,
        for string in next_strings:
            # and send it back to the caller. This is a single "result."
            yield string

            # If we're still generating strings -- that is, we haven't reached
            # our maximum length -- we add more generators to the stack for the
            # next length of strings.
            if maxlen is None or len(string) < maxlen:
                stack.append(generate_next_strings(chars, string))
```

You can try it using `print("\n".join(generate_all_strings("abc", maxlen=5)))`.

Answer (score 0):

The following code will give you all combinations with lengths between `1` and `max_length - 1`:

```
import itertools

combs = []

for i in range(1, max_length):
    c = [list(x) for x in itertools.combinations(using_characts, i)]
    combs.extend(c)
```