# How to get all substrings & all character permutations of all substings?

Tags: python, string, set

I have a string f.e. str = 'abc'

I want to get all combinations like this:

```
'a', 'b', 'c', 'ab', 'ac', 'ba', 'bc', 'ca','cb', 'abc', 'acb', 'bca' , 'bac', 'cab', 'cba'
```

I tried

```
def string_set(str):
    n = len(str) 
    arr = [] 

    for i in range(0,n):  
        for j in range(i,n): 
            arr.append(str[i:(j+1)])

    return arr
```

but it olny gave me:

```
'a', 'ab', 'abc', 'b', 'bc', 'c'.
```

How can I include  the rest ones?

Comment: Since you are doing `str[i:(j+1)]` you are only getting the "contiguous"  substrings. Also, `str` is a very bad choice for a variable name

Comment: @DeepSpace Substrings are contiguous by definition. They just want more than substrings.

Comment: The question which is supposedly answers this question does not answer it. It does not deal with permutations, the OP here wants all permutations as well.

Comment: @zabop Almost, though. Just change combin to permut.

Comment: Yeah, but almost a duplicate is not a duplicate.

Comment: @zabop True, but my point rather was that you might want to try that, as your solution is very complicated.

Comment: Oh ok! Thanks, thats a good point!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import itertools
```

---

You can do, using itertools [permutations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/104420/how-to-generate-all-permutations-of-a-list) & [combinations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51538192/getting-all-combinations-of-a-string-and-its-substrings):

```
def string_set(x):
    arr = [''.join(l) for i in range(len(x)) for l in itertools.combinations(x, i+1)]     
    reslist=[]   
    for eachpermut in arr:
        for each in [''.join(eachpermut) for eachpermut in list(itertools.permutations(eachpermut))]:
            reslist.append(each)
    return reslist
```

If you like everything in one line:

```
def string_set(x):
    return [each for eachpermut in [''.join(l) for i in range(len(x)) for l in itertools.combinations(x, i+1)] for each in [''.join(eachpermut) for eachpermut in list(itertools.permutations(eachpermut))]]
```

`string_set('abc')` returns:

```
['a',
 'b',
 'c',
 'ab',
 'ba',
 'ac',
 'ca',
 'bc',
 'cb',
 'abc',
 'acb',
 'bac',
 'bca',
 'cab',
 'cba']
```

---

If you don't want to import `itertools`, you can just use their [`permutations`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/itertools.html#itertools.permutations) functions only:

```
def permutations(iterable, r=None):
    # permutations('ABCD', 2) --> AB AC AD BA BC BD CA CB CD DA DB DC
    # permutations(range(3)) --> 012 021 102 120 201 210
    pool = tuple(iterable)
    n = len(pool)
    r = n if r is None else r
    if r > n:
        return
    indices = list(range(n))
    cycles = list(range(n, n-r, -1))
    yield tuple(pool[i] for i in indices[:r])
    while n:
        for i in reversed(range(r)):
            cycles[i] -= 1
            if cycles[i] == 0:
                indices[i:] = indices[i+1:] + indices[i:i+1]
                cycles[i] = n - i
            else:
                j = cycles[i]
                indices[i], indices[-j] = indices[-j], indices[i]
                yield tuple(pool[i] for i in indices[:r])
                break
        else:
            return
```

Then just do `permutations` instead of `itertools.permutations` in the above code.

Can do the same with [`combinations`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations).

Comment: I liked this:) btw. How can I do this without itertools library?

Comment: there are no 'ac',  'ca' ((

Comment: oh ok, looking into it...

Comment: @kishmish17 Your title says "all substrings & all of their permutations" and that's what this code does (except for the empty substring). 'ac' and 'ca' are not a permutation of a substring.

Comment: check it now, I think it works

Comment: @superbrain, why not? it is a permutation of a and c.

Comment: You could use **powerset** from [itertools recipes](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools-recipes) with a change to use **permutations** instead of **combinations**.

Comment: @zabop If you argue like that, then you should also say that abbc should be there, as it's a permutation of ab and bc (I don't think so, but apparently you do).

Comment: Yes that is correct - maybe can you suggest a better title? (I edited that title to its current state).

Comment: @blhsing I tried it and was going to post before the post was closed. It permutes all combinations of the powerset. I thought that was what the OP wanted.

Comment: @ChrisCharley Yes, switching combinations to permutations in the powerset recipe would be the correct approach. I've re-opened the question since it isn't exactly a duplicate.

Comment: Edited the question, is it better now?

Comment: Yeah, powerset would be great.

Comment: I was wrong about the output in this answer, now edited it. Now if I do: `set(string_set('abc')) - set(['a', 'b', 'c', 'ab', 'ac', 'ba', 'bc', 'ca','cb', 'abc', 'acb', 'bca' , 'bac', 'cab', 'cba'])`, it gives me an empty set, `set(['a', 'b', 'c', 'ab', 'ac', 'ba', 'bc', 'ca','cb', 'abc', 'acb', 'bca' , 'bac', 'cab', 'cba']) - set(string_set('abc'))` also. (The long list is the OP's desired output.) Are you sure I am wrong? (I am not certain I am right.)