# how to find all the combinations of word from a list

Tags: python-3.x, list

So I Have the str = 'Pizza'
and I have list of words,for example:
list = [ ['pizza'],['izza'] , ['zza'] ]
how can I check all the possible combinations of "Pizza" to check if it is in the list?
without using Numpy command
p
pi
piz
pizz
pizza
I
iz
izz
izza
etc.

Comment: Refer to this answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51538192/getting-all-combinations-of-a-string-and-its-substrings)

Answer (score 0):

```
def check_present_frm_string(a_word: str, check_list: list):
    length = len(a_word)
    i = 0
    combination_list = list()
    while i < length:
        new_word = a_word[i:]
        j = len(new_word)
        while j != 0:
            j_word = new_word[:j]
            if j_word not in combination_list:
                combination_list.append(j_word)
            j -= 1
        i += 1
    for item in check_list:
        if item in combination_list:
            print(f'{item} is a valid combination')
        else:
            print(f'{item} is not a valid combination')


a_list = ['p', 'pi', 'piz', 'pizz', 'pizza', 'I', 'iz', 'izz', 'izza']
a_str = 'Pizza'
check_present_frm_string(a_str, a_list)
```

Results:
p is not a valid combination
pi is not a valid combination
piz is not a valid combination
pizz is not a valid combination
pizza is not a valid combination
I is not a valid combination
iz is a valid combination
izz is a valid combination
izza is a valid combination

Answer (score 0):

Actually,I Recived the word "Pizza" from a list and I Can't create another list with all the combinations like in a_list.
I have to take the string - pizza and from it to create all the combinations.

Answer (score 0):

```
def all_combinations_frm_string(a_word: str):
    length = len(a_word)
    i = 0
    combination_list = list()
    while i < length:
        new_word = a_word[i:]
        j = len(new_word)
        while j != 0:
            j_word = new_word[:j]
            if j_word not in combination_list:
                combination_list.append(j_word)
            j -= 1
        i += 1
    return combination_list

print(all_combinations_frm_string('Pizza'))
```

Result:
['Pizza', 'Pizz', 'Piz', 'Pi', 'P', 'izza', 'izz', 'iz', 'i', 'zza', 'zz', 'z', 'za', 'a']