# Compute all powerset intersections of two lists

Tags: python, list, set, intersection

I found many articles about finding intersection of 2 lists, but in none of them was written how could I get all intersections (maybe it could be called subintersections).

Example:

```
list1 = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
list2 = ['b', 'c', 'd', 'e']

print (find_all_intersections(list1, list2))
```

Output:

```
['b', 'c', 'd', 'bc', 'bd', 'cd', 'bcd']
```

Is there any function which can make this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, it's actually pretty simple. Once you've found the intersection, compute the powerset:

```
from itertools import chain, combinations

s = set(list1).intersection(list2)
[''.join(c) for c in chain.from_iterable(
    combinations(s, r) for r in range(len(s)+1)) if c]
```

```
['b', 'c', 'd', 'bc', 'bd', 'cd', 'bcd']
```

More information on generating powersets can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1482308/how-to-get-all-subsets-of-a-set-powerset).