# Odered permutations in python

Tags: python, permutation

Hi I trying to create function with string argument and return ordered permutation dict.
Example:

word = 'abc';
func(word) - > [a, b, c, ab, ac, bc, abc]

Comment: This is called the [powerset](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html?highlight=powerset). Look under itertools recipies

Comment: Why is bc before abc?

Comment: @ChrisCharley Nitpicking: powerset *without* the empty set.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get all subsets of a set? (powerset)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1482308/how-to-get-all-subsets-of-a-set-powerset). Or [How to get all possible combinations of a list’s elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/464864/how-to-get-all-possible-combinations-of-a-list-s-elements)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[itertools.combinations](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations) returns in lexicographical order

Somthing like

```
def word(w):
   for i in range(len(w)):
      yield from itertools.combinations(w,i+1)
```

Edir:

This is wrong just like powerset, because it does not return all results in lexicographical order.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are referring to a combination.
Permutations are combinations where the different orders in the elements take importance.
If combinations of 'ab' look like ['a', 'b', 'ab'], a permutation looks like ['a', 'b', 'ab', 'ba']

```py
from itertools import combinations

word = 'abc'
my_list = []
for n in range(len(word)):
    my_list.extend([''.join(x) for x in combinations(word, n + 1)])

print(my_list)
```

Result:

```
['a', 'b', 'c', 'ab', 'ac', 'bc', 'abc']
```

Answer (score 0):

`def toString(List):
    return ''.join(List)`

```
def permute(a, l, r): 
if l==r: 
    print toString(a) 
else: 
    for i in xrange(l,r+1): 
        a[l], a[i] = a[i], a[l] 
        permute(a, l+1, r) 
        a[l], a[i] = a[i], a[l]
string = "ABC"
    n = len(string) 
    a = list(string) 
    permute(a, 0, n-1)
```