# Generate all substrings(in lexicographic order)of given string in alphabetical order

Tags: python, string, recursion, backtracking

I recently saw this problem and am really stuck at implementing it.

The problem is to generate all possible alphabetically ordered substrings from given string.

**Smaller Example** : For string `xcv`

I am required to generate the output :

```
c cv cvx v vx x
```

**Bigger Example** : For the string `hgrte`

I am required to generate the following substrings :

```
e
eg
egh
eghr
eghrt
eght
egr
egrt
egt
eh
ehr
ehrt
eht
er
ert
et
g
gh
ghr
ghrt
ght
gr
grt
gt
h
hr
hrt
ht
r
rt
t
```

This is my implementation which didn't produce the desired output.

```py
s = sorted(list(input()))
s = ''.join(s)
for i in range(len(s)):
    for j in range(i+1, len(s)+1):
        temp = s[i:j]
        print(''.join(temp))
```

This is the output of my code :

```
e
eg
egh
eghr
eghrt
g
gh
ghr
ghrt
h
hr
hrt
r
rt
t
[]
```

I know I have to use backtracking and recursion after printing `eghrt`, but I am really stuck at implementing it. 
Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Probably in the smaller example several combinations are missing (cxv, vcx, vxc etcetera). Aren't they?

Comment: @RobertoCaboni these aren't alphabetically ordered.

Comment: No, the alphabets should be in their lexicographic order in the substrings, sorry I will add the constraint to my question. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can iterate through the different lengths and use `itertools.combinations` to produce the combinations of letters:

```
from itertools import combinations
s = sorted(input())
print(*sorted(''.join(c) for i in range(len(s)) for c in combinations(s, i + 1)), sep='\n')
```

Comment: Your a genius, great stuff, can you include some explanation if possible, thanks a lot :)

Comment: Understood it, as you told `combinations` is to produce strings of different lengths and we sort these words in the list.

Answer (score 1):

You could do it without recursion, if recursion isn't an explicit requirement:

```
from itertools import chain, combinations

def powerset(iterable):
    "powerset([1,2,3]) --> () (1,) (2,) (3,) (1,2) (1,3) (2,3) (1,2,3)"
    s = list(iterable)
    return chain.from_iterable(combinations(s, r) for r in range(len(s)+1))

for w in (''.join(sorted(x)) for x in powerset(s) ):
    print(w)
```

The `powerset` function taken from [How to get all subsets of a set? (powerset)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1482308/how-to-get-all-subsets-of-a-set-powerset)

Comment: Have you used `list` as a variable name somewhere in your code? Then you've overwritten the built-in `list` function. DON'T.

Comment: Yes, am sorry ! Your code is easier to understand, thanks a lot !

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to consider non-consecutive sub-strings. An easy way to do this is with itertools.

```
import itertools

word = sorted(list(input()))
print(sorted(set([''.join(j) for i in range(len(word)) for j in itertools.combinations(word, i)])))
```

That will do the job. If you prefer to not use the standard library, you can use bit masking to obtain all possible sub-strings.

Comment: There's no reason to use a set here.

Answer (score 0):

```
s = 'abc'
n = len(s)
p = 2 ** n   # total number of power sets 
res = []
for i in range(1, p):
    tmp = ''
    for j in range(n):
        if i & (1 << j):
            tmp += s[j]
    res.append(tmp)

print(sorted(res))   # ['a', 'ab', 'abc', 'ac', 'b', 'bc', 'c']


# Time Complexity: O(2^n * n)
# Space Complexity: O(n)
```