# Creating combination on list values

Tags: python, grouping, combinations

I have a requirement where say i have a list
lis = ['a','b','c','d','e','f']
I have to now create a combination of them eg:

l1 = [a],['b,c,d,e,f]

l2: [b],[a,c,d,e,f]
.

.

l10 [a,b,c],[d,e,f]
.

l11 [a,b,c,d] [e,f]

The repeated elements on the left and right nodes will be removed:
eg: i don't need two lists as:

l1: [b,c] , [a,d,e,f]

l2: [a,d,e,f], [b,c]

Since they are the same

The pseudo code i have in mind is:
for length = 1, i will take one element from list and club others

similar for length=2, will take two element and club others

till length=len(list)-1, will do the clubbing

and then later remove the duplicates.

Any better solution i could try?

Comment: Do you want the powerset? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1482308/how-to-get-all-subsets-of-a-set-powerset

Comment: @DaniMesejo I think it's a little more than that. It seems like for each subset, it needs to be associated with its complement

Comment: You only need to go up to `len(list)//2`. And it might be worthwhile to just use a set so duplicates never occur. But you'll have to use hashable types.

Comment: Could there be repeated elements in the list?

Comment: repeated elements are not required 
so eventually i will create a tree and these combinations will be nothing but the left and right root nodes. Hence repetition won't matter

Comment: I tried using itertools.combinations but it just throws the combinations from a list values.
i want actually different sets for left/right combination

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get all subsets of a set? (powerset)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1482308/how-to-get-all-subsets-of-a-set-powerset)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may no be optimal, but is very straightforward:

```
from itertools import chain, combinations


def power_set(iterable):
    """power_set([1,2,3]) --> () (1,) (2,) (3,) (1,2) (1,3) (2,3) (1,2,3)"""
    source = list(iterable)
    return chain.from_iterable(combinations(source, r) for r in range(1, len(source) // 2 + 1))


def complement(source, universe):
    return tuple(set(universe) - set(source))


lst = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f']

result = set(frozenset({si, complement(si, lst)}) for si in power_set(lst))

for s, c in result:
    print(s, c)
```

**Output**

```
('a', 'd', 'e') ('f', 'c', 'b')
('f', 'a', 'c', 'b') ('d', 'e')
('b', 'e') ('d', 'f', 'a', 'c')
('a', 'b', 'f') ('d', 'e', 'c')
('e', 'd', 'a', 'f', 'b') ('c',)
('c', 'f') ('d', 'a', 'e', 'b')
('d', 'f') ('a', 'e', 'b', 'c')
('d',) ('e', 'c', 'a', 'f', 'b')
('f', 'a', 'e', 'c') ('b', 'd')
('e', 'c', 'd', 'a', 'b') ('f',)
('b', 'c', 'd') ('f', 'a', 'e')
('a', 'b', 'e') ('d', 'f', 'c')
('b', 'c') ('d', 'f', 'a', 'e')
('f', 'a', 'b') ('c', 'd', 'e')
('d', 'e', 'b', 'c') ('a', 'f')
('c', 'd', 'f') ('a', 'e', 'b')
('e', 'c', 'd', 'f', 'b') ('a',)
('a', 'c') ('d', 'f', 'e', 'b')
('f', 'e', 'c') ('a', 'b', 'd')
('a', 'd') ('f', 'e', 'b', 'c')
('b', 'c', 'e') ('d', 'f', 'a')
('a', 'c', 'e') ('d', 'f', 'b')
('d', 'e', 'f') ('a', 'c', 'b')
('a', 'c', 'd') ('f', 'e', 'b')
('d', 'f', 'e', 'c') ('a', 'b')
('f', 'a', 'e', 'b') ('c', 'd')
('d', 'a', 'c') ('b', 'e', 'f')
('a', 'e') ('d', 'f', 'c', 'b')
('a', 'b', 'c') ('d', 'f', 'e')
('a', 'd', 'f') ('e', 'b', 'c')
('d', 'e', 'b') ('a', 'c', 'f')
('c', 'd', 'a', 'f', 'b') ('e',)
('b',) ('e', 'c', 'd', 'a', 'f')
('e', 'f') ('d', 'a', 'c', 'b')
('d', 'c', 'b') ('a', 'e', 'f')
('b', 'f') ('d', 'a', 'e', 'c')
('d', 'a', 'e') ('b', 'c', 'f')
('b', 'd', 'e') ('f', 'a', 'c')
('a', 'e', 'c') ('b', 'd', 'f')
('c', 'e') ('d', 'f', 'a', 'b')
('d', 'a', 'b') ('c', 'e', 'f')
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. but any idea how to eliminate the duplicates?
eg:
one results is ('b','c') and ('a','d','e','f')
and other is ('c','b') and ('a','d','e','f')

Comment: just have `range(1, len(s) // 2 + 1)`, it'll help with some duplicates and it'll make things a lot faster

Comment: @AkshatShreemali I've updated the solution with the suggestion from MZ, see if its working correctly