# Python permutations to create combinations using all and partial elements of a list

Tags: python

I have a python list as below

```
l = ['water', 'park', 'kit']
```

To get all combinations of these elements, I'm using this

```
p = list(itertools.permutations(l))
```

For which I get result as below:
`[('water', 'park', 'kit'), ('water', 'kit', 'park'), ('park', 'water', 'kit'), ('park', 'kit', 'water'), ('kit', 'water', 'park'), ('kit', 'park', 'water')]`

I also need partial combinations of the elements as well, something like below:
`[('water'), ('water', 'kit'), ('park',), ('park', 'kit'), ('kit', 'park')]`

Is there a way to populate these combinations as well?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get all subsets of a set? (powerset)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1482308/how-to-get-all-subsets-of-a-set-powerset)

Comment: thanks for pointing out to the right post.