# How do I get all combinations of a list with repeating values

Tags: python, combinations, permutation

I have a program that needs to get all possible combinations of items in a list, but what I have found so far doesn't give me what I need. From a list of say `[1,2,3]` I need the output,

`(1)(2)(3)(1,1)(1,2)(1,3)(2,1)(2,2)(2,3)(3,1)(3,2)(3,3)`

But all the solutions I've found give me an answer that doesn't repeat values, is there a library that can do this for me, because itertools doesn't give me the right output. Otherwise I'll just right a function myself.

Comment: If you want (1), (2), and (3), you probably also want (1,2,3), right?

Comment: Yeah, but I figure with a function for those values i can also get that

Comment: See my updated answer below.

Answer (score 3):

Your original desired result was just the Cartesian product of the list with itself:

```
my_list = [1,2,3]
list(itertools.product(my_list, my_list))
#=> [(1, 1), (1, 2), (1, 3), (2, 1), (2, 2), (2, 3), (3, 1), (3, 2), (3, 3)]
```

But you edited it to include (1,), (2,), and (3,). In that case you may be asking for the power set instead - that's the set of all the subsets of the original. You can use the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1482308/how-to-get-all-subsets-of-a-set-powerset), but be aware that the result will include both the empty list and the original list in its entirety.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with list comprehension:

```py
a = [1,2,3]
[(i,j) for i in a for j in a]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a recursive generator function:

```
def combos(d, l, c = []):
  yield tuple(c)
  if len(c) < l:
     yield from [i for b in d for i in combos(d, l, c+[b])]

_, *vals = combos([1,2,3], 2)
```

Output:

```
[(1,), (1, 1), (1, 2), (1, 3), (2,), (2, 1), (2, 2), (2, 3), (3,), (3, 1), (3, 2), (3, 3)]
```