# Getting a powerset of a list of lists

Tags: python, hash, combinations

I'm given a list of lists `s`:

```
s = [["a1", "A"], ["b4", "B"], ["a3", "A"], ["d6", "D"], ["c4", "C"]]
```

(note that the elements in a list do not necessarily begin with a same letter. I modified the data here for convenience.)

My goal is to sort each list to a category by its second element, and get all possible combinations by picking at most one element in each category.

I first hashed the list of lists to a dictionary:

```
dic = {i[1]: [] for i in s}
for i in s:
    # set the value of the first item key to the second item
    dic[i[1]].append(i[0])

dic
>>> {'A': ['a1', 'a3'], 'B': ['b4'], 'C': ['c4'], 'D': ['d6']}
```

The number of all possible combinations, hence the length of a powerset of `s`, should return `23`:

```
{'a1'},
{'a3'},
{'b4'},
{'c4'}, 
{'d6'}, 
{'a1', 'b4'}, 
{'a1', 'c4'}, 
{'a1', 'd6'}, 
{'a3', 'b4'}, 
{'a3', 'c4'}, 
{'a3', 'd6'}, 
{'b4', 'c4'}, 
{'b4', 'd6'}, 
{'c4', 'd6'}, 
{'a1', 'b4', 'c4'}, 
{'a1', 'b4', 'd6'}, 
{'a1', 'c4', 'd6'}, 
{'a3', 'b4', 'c4'}, 
{'a3', 'b4', 'd6'}, 
{'a3', 'c4', 'd6'}, 
{'b4', 'c4', 'd6'}, 
{'a1', 'b4', 'c4', 'd6'}, 
{'a3', 'b4', 'c4', 'd6'}
```

I initially was going to put multiple `for` loops, but since I have no guarantee in how many `key` I would have in my `s` (which would also put my time complexity at O(N^x)), I used `itertools.chain` and `itertools.combinations` as per [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1482308/how-to-get-all-subsets-of-a-set-powerset):

```
def powerset(s:list):
    return chain.from_iterable(combinations(s, r) for r in range(1, len(s)+1))
```

The problem is that this only takes elements in a single list to account, hence neglects the constraint: 'not taking more than one element from each list at most'. Flattening a list would disregard the categories, so I've not attempted to do so.

Any insights to tackle this problem would be appreciated.

Comment: Why doesn't your expected output also include `{}`? That's normally considered part of a powerset or cartesian product.

Comment: Please also see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/533905/get-the-cartesian-product-of-a-series-of-lists (I reopened; this isn't close enough to be a duplicate, and the answer you're given shows a key and non-obvious technique.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

@don'ttalkjustcode's answer works but unnecessarily incurs the overhead of adding dummy values, and also produces an empty set, which is not required by the question.

A more direct approach would be to use `itertools.combinations` to pick lists from the dict of lists to pass to `itertools.product` to produce the desired combinations:

```
from itertools import product, combinations

print(*(
    set(p)
    for r in range(len(dic))
    for c in combinations(dic.values(), r + 1)
    for p in product(*c)
), sep='\n')
```

This outputs:

```
{'a1'}
{'a3'}
{'b4'}
{'c4'}
{'d6'}
{'a1', 'b4'}
{'a3', 'b4'}
{'a1', 'c4'}
{'a3', 'c4'}
{'d6', 'a1'}
{'d6', 'a3'}
{'c4', 'b4'}
{'d6', 'b4'}
{'d6', 'c4'}
{'a1', 'c4', 'b4'}
{'a3', 'c4', 'b4'}
{'d6', 'a1', 'b4'}
{'d6', 'a3', 'b4'}
{'d6', 'a1', 'c4'}
{'d6', 'a3', 'c4'}
{'d6', 'c4', 'b4'}
{'d6', 'a1', 'c4', 'b4'}
{'d6', 'a3', 'c4', 'b4'}
```

Answer (score 3):

You could turn each category list like `['a1', 'a3']` into a list like `[[], ['a1'], ['a3']]`, take the product of those, and chain each product ([Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NY7NCsMgEITvPsXeVtNQKCmlFHroz1uIB2sSIiQqagIl5NltYuheZr4d2Fn3jZ011dX5lFpvB9Cx8dHaPoAenPURnLf1qGIJqpPaEFJrBXeY8YE34ChPWALKCsUqz7z6nDO8Mqgd3hnqC4qFtNaDA23@l2lBORcCDsB5ELDFYYun3U@bX0uPk@zHJlDG2I3AOs5rE@lc5L9o4djCUvoB)):

```
from itertools import product, chain

dic = {'A': ['a1', 'a3'], 'B': ['b4'], 'C': ['c4'], 'D': ['d6']}
for p in product(*([[]] + [[s] for s in v] for v in dic.values())):
    print({*chain(*p)})
```

Or add a special "skip"-value to each category and filter it out ([Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TY/bCoMwDIbv@xShV62III4xhF3s8BalF50HDLg21DoY4rO7qoMtV/nIl5@E3qFztjiRX5bWuydgaHxwrh8An@R8APKuHquQQtUZtIwNcAaluMl5CvzCdQqKPw4rXHcwxd@kPq5w36HatBvXmrEaqxg0ocp1GfO0htZ5QEALw8x@fckgVrTVqurMEDW2FqjKXEu2ibSK3zNFEtXsZfqxGYSU@zZ5tEFMyfaBSEjOclk@)):

```
from itertools import product, chain

skip = object()

dic = {'A': ['a1', 'a3'], 'B': ['b4'], 'C': ['c4'], 'D': ['d6']}
for p in product(*([skip] + v for v in dic.values())):
    print(set(p) - {skip})
```

Hmm, I started with your already processed `dic` because you did that well, but ... if you start with `dic = {i[1]: [skip] for i in s}` right away, then you don't need to add it later and can just do this ([Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TY7LCkIhEIb3PsXgSuMURRERtOjyFuLCPEbTRQe1IKJnP2knqFnNx//NhR75GPx0QbHrDjFcAbOLOYRLArxSiBkohvZmcwP2aNAzlmAFSnEz4Q3wNdcNKL6fVdj0YKZ/STuvsOvBfrQt17qsOSOVTWF/cjYLyVq0BZ@oJnoJqqYaDiECAnpIL/brlwxKFV9VWY8MkfOtQDXWkn08qt73bzEo5uhuLjeXhJT9MEX0WSSXBUkYwrOee8muewM)):

```
for p in product(*dic.values()):
    print(set(p) - {skip})
```

Doing the same with the first allows ([Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TY/bCoMwDIbv@xShV62III4xhF3s8BalF50HDLg21DoY4rO7qoMtV/nIl5@E3qFztjiRX5bWuydgaHxwrh8An@R8APKuHquQQtUZtIwNcAaluMl5CvzCdQqKPw4rXHcwxd@kPq5w36HatBvXmrEaqxg0ocp1GfO0htZ5QEALw8x@fckgVrTVqurMEDW2FqjKXEu2ibSK3zNFEtXsZfqxGYSU@zZ5tEFMyfaBSEjOclk@)):

```
for p in product(*dic.values()):
    print({*chain(*p)})
```

Output of all (last two might show different orders due to string hash randomization):

```
set()
{'d6'}
{'c4'}
{'d6', 'c4'}
{'b4'}
{'d6', 'b4'}
{'b4', 'c4'}
{'d6', 'b4', 'c4'}
{'a1'}
{'d6', 'a1'}
{'a1', 'c4'}
{'d6', 'a1', 'c4'}
{'b4', 'a1'}
{'d6', 'b4', 'a1'}
{'b4', 'a1', 'c4'}
{'d6', 'b4', 'a1', 'c4'}
{'a3'}
{'d6', 'a3'}
{'c4', 'a3'}
{'d6', 'c4', 'a3'}
{'b4', 'a3'}
{'d6', 'b4', 'a3'}
{'c4', 'b4', 'a3'}
{'d6', 'c4', 'b4', 'a3'}
```

Comment: Exactly so. The key insight here is that for an input list of N elements, there are N+1 possibilities: each of the elements, or no element. So we need an extra level of list wrapping in order to account for the number of elements to use for a given input, hence the transformation.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel Added an alternative without wrapping :-)

Comment: That's the same kind of workaround, just with filtering dummy values instead of flattening a dummy layer of lists. But yeah, I can see reasons to prefer that aesthetically.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel Third solution (also applicable to first one) is prettiest...