# Depth-first enumeration of powerset (of ordered set)

Tags: python, algorithm, set

Given an ordered set `[1,2,3,...]` of elements, how do I enumerate the powerset of this set in a depth-first way? That is, I want to see all of the subsets containing `1` before I see any subsets without `1`, then all of the remaining subsets containing `2` (but not `1`) before subsets without `2` (or `1`), etc.

That is, for the set `[1,2,3,4]`, I want to generate the following tuples in order:

```
()
(1,)
(1, 2)
(1, 2, 3)
(1, 2, 3, 4)
(1, 2, 4)
(1, 3)
(1, 3, 4)
(1, 4)
(2,)
(2, 3)
(2, 3, 4)
(2, 4)
(3,)
(3, 4)
(4,)
```

Ideally, I'd be able to do this in a recursive way, without needing to keep track of which subsets I've already visited.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
def powerset(items):
    # yields all sequences that start with prefix, and contain
    # at least one element of items, in order
    def internal(prefix, items):
        if not items:
            return
        first, *rest = items
        yield [*prefix, first]
        yield from internal([*prefix, first], rest)
        yield from internal(prefix, rest)

    yield []
    yield from internal([], items)
```

And then:

```
for x in powerset([1, 2, 3, 4]):
    print(x)

[]
[1]
[1, 2]
[1, 2, 3]
[1, 2, 3, 4]
[1, 2, 4]
[1, 3]
[1, 3, 4]
[1, 4]
[2]
[2, 3]
[2, 3, 4]
[2, 4]
[3]
[3, 4]
[4]
```

Comment: Clever -- this avoids loops.

Answer (score 1):

The key here is to see that we can take a single element, and then prepend it to the powerset of the elements which come after it. That is, first we take `1` and generate the powerset of `[2,3,4]`, and prepend `1` to each subset.

```
(1,) + ()         -> (1,)
(1,) + (2,)       -> (1, 2)
(1,) + (2, 3)     -> (1, 2, 3)
(1,) + (2, 3, 4)  -> (1, 2, 3, 4)
(1,) + (2, 4)     -> (1, 2, 4)
(1,) + (3,)       -> (1, 3)
(1,) + (3, 4)     -> (1, 3, 4)
(1,) + (4,)       -> (1, 4)
```

Then we take the next element (`2`), and prepend it to the powerset of the following elements (`[3,4]`):

```
(2,) + ()         -> (2,)
(2,) + (3,)       -> (2, 3)
(2,) + (3, 4)     -> (2, 3, 4)
(2,) + (4,)       -> (2, 4)
```

and so on, until we run out of elements.

We can do this with a python generator:

```py
def powerset(seq):
    def _powerset(seq, elm):
        yield seq
        for i in range(len(elm)):
            yield from _powerset(seq+(elm[i],), elm[i+1:])
    yield from _powerset(tuple(), list(seq))
```

Answer (score 0):

**Edit:** Unfortunately this does not generate the powerset in the desired order.

---

As per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1482316/7304977), it seems other users have found the builtin `itertools` implementation to be the fastest:

```
from itertools import chain, combinations

def powerset(iterable):
    s = list(iterable)
    return chain.from_iterable(combinations(s, r) for r in range(len(s)+1))
```

Comment: That answer doesn’t generate the subsets in the desired order, unfortunately.

Comment: @kc9jud You are right, thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 0):

You can use recursion to traverse in DFS fashion to get this result.
Below is an example program.

```py
def powerset(arr):
    subsets=[]
    for i in range(len(arr)):
        subsets.append([arr[i]])
        for j in powerset(arr[i+1:]):
            subsets.append([arr[i]]+j)
    return subsets
```

Output:

```py
[[1]
[1, 2]
[1, 2, 3]
[1, 2, 3, 4]
[1, 2, 4]
[1, 3]
[1, 3, 4]
[1, 4]
[2]
[2, 3]
[2, 3, 4]
[2, 4]
[3]
[3, 4]
[4]]
```