# Using min and max on sublists and creating a list without using "for loop" outside reduce function

Tags: python, list, sublist, functools

```
from functools import reduce
for _ in range(int(input())):
    N = int(input())
    l1 = list(map(int,input().split()))
    def powerset(lst):
        return reduce(lambda result, x: result + [subset + [x] for subset in result],
                      lst, [[]])
        
    #https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1482308/how-to-get-all-subsets-of-a-set-powerset

    lst = (powerset(l1))
    print(lst)
    ivlst = []
    
    for i in range(1, len(lst)):
        ivlst.append((min(lst[i])*max(lst[i])))
    print(min(ivlst), end=" ")
    print(max(ivlst))
```

Sample input:

```
2
2
2 2
3
5 0 9
```

Sample output:

```
4 4
0 81
```

The above code does the following:

1. It takes the input as N, where N is the number of elements in the list.
2. Then it takes the input as the elements of the list.
3. Then it creates a function called powerset which takes a list as an argument and returns all the subsets of that list.
4. Then it calls the reduce function on the powerset function with the list as the first argument and the empty list as the second argument.
5. The reduce function will return a list of lists.
6. The ivlst variable is used to store the values of the minimum and maximum of the subsets.
7. Then it iterates over the range from 1 to the length of the list.
8. For each iteration, it appends the multiplication of minimum and maximum of the subset to the ivlst list.
9. Finally, it prints the minimum and maximum of the ivlst list.

The time complexity is O(2^n) where n is the number of elements in the given set.

I need a way to not use the *for loop* for getting the min and max values of all sublists, rather I need **to get a list containing multiplication of min and max values of all sublists as output from the powerset function itself**.

Comment: Weclome to SO. Is it a homework or assignment?

Comment: It was a basic question to get a list of multiplication of maximum and minimum elements of all sublists but I am not satisfied with the time complexity of my solution. ty:)

Comment: The description of step 8 is not the same as your code.

Comment: Step 8: For each iteration, it appends the *(multiplication of) minimum and maximum of the subset to the ivlst list.

Comment: this should be in [codereview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com)

Comment: @XxJames07- How can I switch this question over to Code Review forum?

Comment: You can post it over there, go to https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/ask and paste the markdown in the body.

Answer (score 0):

The equivalent code of your `powerset` function is as follows:

```
from itertools import islice

def powerset(lst):
    ret = [[]]
    for elem in lst:
        for subset in islice(ret, len(ret)):
            ret.append(subset + [elem])
    return ret
```

We no longer build and record the remaining subsets in the inner loop, but only record the minimum and maximum values of the subsets, so that our operating costs will be greatly reduced (from `O(n * 2^n)` to `O(2^n)`, because the generation algorithm of power sets will not be faster than `O(2^n)`, and the minimum and maximum values calculated for each subset are `O(n)`):

```
from itertools import islice

def powerset_extremum(lst):
    ret = [(float('inf'), float('-inf'))]
    for elem in lst:
        for min_, max_ in islice(ret, len(ret)):
            ret.append((min(min_, elem), max(max_, elem)))
    return ret
```

Simple test:

```
>>> powerset([2, 1, 4, 3])
[[],
 [2],
 [1],
 [2, 1],
 [4],
 [2, 4],
 [1, 4],
 [2, 1, 4],
 [3],
 [2, 3],
 [1, 3],
 [2, 1, 3],
 [4, 3],
 [2, 4, 3],
 [1, 4, 3],
 [2, 1, 4, 3]]
>>> powerset_extremum([2, 1, 4, 3])
[(inf, -inf),
 (2, 2),
 (1, 1),
 (1, 2),
 (4, 4),
 (2, 4),
 (1, 4),
 (1, 4),
 (3, 3),
 (2, 3),
 (1, 3),
 (1, 3),
 (3, 4),
 (2, 4),
 (1, 4),
 (1, 4)]
```

Then you can easily get their multiplication:

```
>>> from itertools import starmap, islice
>>> from operator import mul
>>> list(starmap(mul, islice(powerset_extremum([2, 1, 4, 3]), 1, None)))
[4, 1, 2, 16, 8, 4, 4, 9, 6, 3, 3, 12, 8, 4, 4]
```

I know that this does not meet your requirement of not using the for loop, but it is obviously much faster than eliminating the explicit for loop through some built-in functions after getting the power set.

Answer (score 0):

You could maximize the production of the `powerset` function, in fact,
the Python [`itertools`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools-recipes) page has exactly a `powerset` recipe:

```
def powerset(iterable):
    "powerset([1,2,3]) --> () (1,) (2,) (3,) (1,2) (1,3) (2,3) (1,2,3)"
    s = list(iterable)
    return chain.from_iterable(combinations(s, r) for r in range(len(s)+1))
```

or you can achieve by:

```
from more_itertools import powerset
```