# How to make tables with X amount of booleans with all possible values?

Tags: python, python-3.x

How do i iterate through all possible X boolean values? i.e i have 2 booleans, how do i make a table with all truths and falses?

like:

- A 0 0 1 1
- B 0 1 0 1

Comment: what format is the data in? what does "table" mean for you?  where do you get this data from? you provide absolutely no info regarding this.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get all subsets of a set? (powerset)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1482308/how-to-get-all-subsets-of-a-set-powerset)

Comment: @BijayRegmi lets just say i need a list of tuples formatted like [(0,0,0),(0,0,1),(0,1,0)...] and so on. answer on timrau's suggestion also includes nulls i do not need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to iterate over the `2 ** number of variables` integers. The following example for 4 variables:

```
variables = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
lv = len(variables)

print(''.join(variables))
print('=' * lv)
for i in range(2**lv):
    print(f"{i:0{lv}b}")
```

will produce the following:

```
ABCD
====
0000
0001
0010
0011
0100
0101
0110
0111
1000
1001
1010
1011
1100
1101
1110
1111
```

Comment: thanks! a quick question: does {i:0{lv}b} format the number to be binary?

Comment: @PythonUser - the `b` in `{i:0{lv}b}` is what makes the `int` to print in binary. The whole `{i:0{lv}b}` means  "print `i` in binary format with `lv` digits, and fill with `0s` if `i` can be represented with less digits than `lv`"