# How would you print out all permutations of a string (include the cases where you wouldn't use some characters)

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm writing some python code to test a link with a bunch of different permutations of the possible characters heres my code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.chrome()
chars = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ1234567890"
numatts = int(input("How Many Times To Attempt? >> "))

for i in range(numatts):
    driver.open("LINKHERE" + "/" + "Each permutation")
    #Code Stuff....
```

For Example, If LINKHERE is 'google.com', and numatts = 27, I want the output:

```
google.com/A
google.com/B
google.com/C
google.com/D
google.com/E
google.com/F
google.com/G
google.com/H
google.com/I
google.com/J
google.com/K
google.com/L
google.com/M
google.com/N
google.com/O
google.com/P
google.com/Q
google.com/R
google.com/S
google.com/T
google.com/U
google.com/V
google.com/W
google.com/X
google.com/Y
google.com/Z
google.com/AA
.
.
.
```

and for longer strings, like "test".

```
google.com/t
google.com/et
google.com/est
google.com/tset
```

(and more) would all be a part of the output

Comment: Loop over the lengths. So first get all the permutations of length 1, then all the permutations of length 2, and so on.

Comment: If you want permutations, have a look at `itertools.permutations`.

Comment: I believe the thing you are looking for is a powerset.
Please, [see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1482308/how-to-get-all-subsets-of-a-set-powerset)

Comment: I wasn't able to effectively implement powersets, but I found someone else who wrote code that has the same idea as mine, just executed differently (the idea of the code doesn't matter, this matter has been resolved, for my case at least, someone else might need this)