# how to create a dynamic list in a loop where all combinations are tried from 1 to 360 is inserted and removed

Tags: python, list, dynamic-list

I want to create a dynamic List i Python that will go in to a loop.
The loop will be like.

```
for t in range(360):
   list = [?]
   # "more code to come"
```

The list will be dynamic and will change as followed while looping.

```
list = [1]
list = [1, 2]
list = [1, 2, 3, n]
list = [1, 3]
list = [1, 3, 4, n]
```

After all combinations with 1 it will loop to 2 and make the same.

```
list = [2]
list = [2, 3]
list = [2, 3, 4, n]
list = [2, 4]
list = [2, 4, 5, n]
```

The list will go in to a model that will be in the loop.

Comment: Please edit the question to show us the code for your latest attempt and where you got stuck. See also: [ask] and [help/on-topic].

Comment: I would say this is what you need: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1482316/12575557