# Writing integers as sum of kth power distinct integers

Tags: python, python-3.x, math, optimization

Given an n integer (n >= 1), and a number k, return all possible ways to write n as kth power different integers.
For instance, if n = 100 and k = 2:

```
100 = 1**2 + 3**2 + 4**2 + 5**2 + 7**2
    = 6**2 + 8**2
    = 10**2
```

or if k = 3:

```
100 = 1**3 + 2**3 + 3**3 + 4**3
```

So `program(100,2)` returns something like `[(2, [1, 3, 4, 5, 7]), (2, [6, 8]), (2, [10])]`,
and `program(100,3)` `[(3, [1, 2, 3, 4])]`.

Everything works fine, as long as the input n is small, or k is "big" (>=3).
My approach was to first get a list of all integers, whose kth power is <= n.

```
def possible_powers(n,k):
    arr,i = [],1
    while i**k <= n:
        arr.append(i)
        i += 1
    return arr
```

Then (and here's the mistake), I created all subsets of this list (as lists):

```
def subsets(L):
    subsets = [[]]
    for i in L:
        subsets += [subset+[i] for subset in subsets]
    return subsets
```

And finally I cycled through all these subsets, raising each element to the kth power and adding them together, selecting only the ones that add up to n.

```
def kth_power_sum(arr,k):
    return sum([i**k for i in arr])

def solutions(n,k):
    return [(k,i) for i in subsets(possible_powers(n,k)) if kth_power_sum(i,k) == n]
```

I know the problem is with the subset-creation, but I have no clue how to optimize this. Like, if I try solutions(1000,2), it creates a large set, which takes up more than 4GB memory. My guess would be to sieve out a few subsets, but that wouldn't help much, unless I have a very efficient sieve.

Any help is greatly appreciated. If something isn't clear, or I made a mistake in posting this, please tell me.

Comment: I don't have time to dig into this right now, but have a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1482308/how-to-get-all-subsets-of-a-set-powerset

Comment: In [`itertools` documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools-recipes) you have how to write the function `powerset` lazily evaluated: only one subset is stored in memory at a time.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @Swifty. I skimmed through that post, but I don't think my powerset function is bad (am I wrong?), but the fact that I create an entire powerset, which in case of subsets(1000,2) if a 2**31 long list (not very optimal).

Comment: I think the way to go here is with some DP algorithm

Comment: Take a look at this answer: [Finding all possible combinations of numbers to reach a given sum](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4633515)
modify it to use powers seems pretty straightforward.

Comment: @JorgeLuis so you're saying that my program stores the entire powerset, messing up the memory, but the `itertools` powerset stores only one of the subsets and cycles through them?

Comment: @ReggieFloarde Yes. Only stores one at a time.

Comment: @JorgeLuis Thank you. My only concern is the time now. Is the `itertools` version slower or faster, or is it the same as mine?

Comment: @ReggieFloarde Quite faster. For a list of size 6 on my machine yours is almost 60% slower than `itertools`. Which will get worse in bigger lists. But is not fast enough for `solutions(1000, 2)`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you implement this as a recursive generator, you won't need to store a large number of values (not even the results):

```
def powersum(n,k,b=1):
    bk = b**k
    while bk < n:
        for bases in powersum(n-bk,k,b+1):
            yield [b]+bases
        b += 1
        bk = b**k
    if bk == n :
        yield [b]
        
print(*powersum(100,2)) # [1, 3, 4, 5, 7] [6, 8] [10]
print(*powersum(100,3)) # [1, 2, 3, 4]
print(sum(1 for _ in powersum(1000,2))) # 1269 solutions
print(sum(1 for _ in powersum(2000,2))) # 27526 solutions (6 seconds)
```

*Note that this still has an exponential time complexity so it will be much slower for slightly larger values of n*

```
print(sum(1 for _ in powersum(2200,2))) # 44930 solutions (12 seconds)
print(sum(1 for _ in powersum(2500,2))) # 91021 solutions (25 seconds)
print(sum(1 for _ in powersum(2800,2))) # 175625 solutions (55 seconds)
print(sum(1 for _ in powersum(3100,2))) # 325067 solutions (110 seconds)
```

[EDIT] For future reference, here is Kelly Bundy's cached version which runs considerably faster.  Posting it here in case his demo link gets broken:

```
from functools import cache
from time import time

@cache                  
def powersum(n,k,b=1):
    bk = b**k
    res = []
    while bk < n:
        for bases in powersum(n-bk,k,b+1):
            res.append([b]+bases)
        b += 1
        bk = b**k
    if bk == n :
        res.append([b])
    return res
```

*Note: although the cache will consume some memory, it will be nowhere near the size the full powerset of all possible combinations.*

Comment: Nice answer. 2000,2 in 6 seconds is very impressive

Comment: You could speed it up by returning lists instead of iterators and decorating with `functools.cache`.

Comment: I did try lru_cache with list outputs but, but it didn't seem to make a meaningful difference (either I didn't do it right or there isn't enough reuse of parameter patterns).  In any case, I was aiming at minimal memory usage for this particular answer.

Comment: What limit did you use? With @cache, I get 2000,2 in 0.4 seconds and 3100,2 in 3 seconds. [Demo](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=VVFBbsMgEFSvvGKPJrajuL1UUZH6jyiqjAMyIl4QYEV9Sy-5pI_KawLYbuo9MTuzo9nl59d-h97g9Xobg6zf7y9aOjOAHLELxpw9qMEaF6Bru16QzAU1iKWd3oR8TuxJSLDmIpwfhwIrXXHW0D2BWFwDA77Z6Iyc8BEejhlcenUWSfABOIlTSeOAtz4KFf4zrblOvuXiu1R03LbWCjwVB34s8yT9U3AoGTRPuAqjZG4wQHh6rv3onDqMDhNFiA9t3J7l_QtKrFMYipSwycm_Vqnfmt2ueqW0muVQQ56n083n0y9f8AA).

Comment: I'm using python 3.7 and forgot to specify a number in `@lru_cache()` so I didn't see an improvement and came to the wrong conclusion.  Giving it a million (instead of the default 128) does provide the expected performance boost.

Comment: Ok :-). Or use `lru_cache(None)`. Some statistics: for 2000,2 the uncached function gets called 8,944,901 times. When cached, it gets called only 31,840 times, and `powersum.cache_info()` reports`CacheInfo(hits=182585, misses=31840, maxsize=None, currsize=31840)`.

Answer (score 1):

your problem is that you are keeping too many irrelevant combinations in `subsets`, I wrote here some code that saves only the relevant lists, so that should do the trick,
(I wrote it here in multiple lines so it will be easier to understand )

```
def my_solutions(n,k):
    subsets = []
    kth_root = int(n**(1/k))# kth_root of n is the upper bound
    relevant_list = range(1,kth_root+1)
    for comb_size in range(1,kth_root+1):
        for comb in combinations(relevant_list, comb_size):
            sum_comb = sum([x**k for x in comb])
            if (sum_comb == n):
                subsets.append(list(comb))
    return subsets
```

here is the same code but written in one-liner to maximize efficiency

```
def my_solutions_one_linner(n,k):
    subsets = []
    kth_root = int(n**(1/k))# kth_root of n is the upprt bound
    relevant_list = range(1,kth_root+1)
    ans =  [[list(comb) for comb in combinations(relevant_list, comb_size) if sum([x**k for x in comb]) == n] for comb_size in range(1,kth_root+1)]
    return [lst for lst in ans if lst!=[]]
```

Comment: would you say that the optimal solution would be to use map , or do you have another idea ?

edited: I just tried using map instead and got slightly worse results, so if you know a better way to solve this problem I would like to know :)

Comment: thanks for the tip, that was a good one :)

Comment: I just tried it and for some reason, it was also slightly slower (but I also thought it would be faster ), anyway, thank you for the tip , I am trying to write a more efficient python code and i really appreciate any help i can get :)

Comment: I posted a faster code.

Answer (score 1):

My solution is based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4632322/finding-all-possible-combinations-of-numbers-to-reach-a-given-sum/4633515#4633515) to the question [Finding all possible combinations of numbers to reach a given sum](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4632322). The goal in the linked question is reaching a value `target` by adding elements in a list `numbers`. In our case, `numbers` will be the integers from `1` to `target**(1/k)` raised to `k`.

This is the function from the other answer.
The only modification is that we know the `numbers` are in increasing order.
This means we can stop the iteration earlier.
If `numbers[0]` is too big, so will be the rest of the following powers.

```
def subset_sum(numbers: list[int], target: int, partial: list[int]=[], partial_sum: int=0):
    if partial_sum == target:
        yield partial
        return
    if numbers and (partial_sum + numbers[0]) > target:
        return
    for i, n in enumerate(numbers):
        remaining = numbers[i + 1:]
        yield from subset_sum(remaining, target, partial + [n], partial_sum + n)
```

Now lets call this function properly.
The important point here is that `subset_sum` needs the powers, but our solution will use the numbers without rising them.
To get so, let's define a dictionary where the keys are the powers and the values are the numbers that will be in our answer.
After so, we just have to give `subset_sum` a list with our dictionary keys.

```
def solutions(n, k):
    kth_root = next(i for i in itertools.count() if i**k>n) - 1
    powers_dict = {i**k: i for i in range(1, kth_root+1)}
    powers = list(powers_dict.keys())
    return [[powers_dict[i] for i in answer] for answer in subset_sum(powers, n)]
```

On my machine this code took 9 seconds to complete `solutions(2000, 2)`.

Answer (score 1):

@Reggie-florade and @Ohad-sharet, you can make the code run faster. Please see the below code. My solution is very much similar to @Ohad-sharet but runs significantly faster. My function name is "kth_power_and_n".

```py
from itertools import combinations
import time
import math
import pandas as pd

def my_solutions_one_linner(n,k):
    subsets = []
    kth_root = int(n**(1/k))# kth_root of n is the upprt bound
    relevant_list = range(1,kth_root+1)
    ans =  [[list(comb) for comb in combinations(relevant_list, comb_size) if sum([x**k for x in comb]) == n] for comb_size in range(1,kth_root+1)]
    return [lst for lst in ans if lst!=[]]  

def kth_power_and_n(n, k):
    UpperLimit = int(math.floor(n**(1/k)))
    Matrix = list(map(lambda x: x**k,range(1,UpperLimit+1)))
    Final_Solution_List = []
    for i in range(1,len(Matrix)+1):
        Generated_Combinations = combinations(Matrix,i)
        for eachCombination in Generated_Combinations:
            if sum(eachCombination) == n:
                Final_Solution_List.append(sorted(list(map(lambda x: int(round(x**(1/k))), eachCombination))))
    return Final_Solution_List

Solution_Dict = {"n":[],"k":[],"time taken 1":[],"time taken 2":[],"Solution Found 1":[],"Solution Found 2":[]}

                
for n in [50,100,250,500]:
    for k in [2,3,4]:
        ## Previous Solution time taken
        Start = time.time()
        Solution = my_solutions_one_linner(n,k)
        Time_Taken = time.time()-Start
        Solution_Dict["n"].append(n)
        Solution_Dict["k"].append(k)
        Solution_Dict["time taken 1"].append(Time_Taken)        
        if Solution:
            Solution_Dict["Solution Found 1"].append(True)
        else:
            Solution_Dict["Solution Found 1"].append(False)

        ## Significantly faster code
        Start = time.time()
        Solution = kth_power_and_n(n,k)
        Time_Taken = time.time()-Start
        Solution_Dict["time taken 2"].append(Time_Taken)        
        if Solution:
            Solution_Dict["Solution Found 2"].append(True)
        else:
            Solution_Dict["Solution Found 2"].append(False)


DF_One_Liner = pd.DataFrame(data=Solution_Dict)
DF_One_Liner["Time Gain Ratio"] = DF_One_Liner["time taken 1"]/DF_One_Liner["time taken 2"]
print(DF_One_Liner)
```

Below is a time comparison of two methods.

```bash
      n  k  time taken 1  time taken 2  Solution Found 1  Solution Found 2  Time Gain Ratio
0    50  2      0.000170      0.000047              True              True         3.627551
1    50  3      0.000012      0.000007             False             False         1.758621
2    50  4      0.000007      0.000005             False             False         1.333333
3   100  2      0.001503      0.000185              True              True         8.142119
4   100  3      0.000019      0.000011              True              True         1.723404
5   100  4      0.000010      0.000006             False             False         1.833333
6   250  2      0.067290      0.006028              True              True        11.163476
7   250  3      0.000073      0.000018             False             False         4.135135
8   250  4      0.000010      0.000006             False             False         1.720000
9   500  2     11.933419      0.870651              True              True        13.706314
10  500  3      0.000185      0.000036             False             False         5.132450
11  500  4      0.000019      0.000009             False             False         2.135135
```

Comment: very impressive, do you think you could explain why your code runs faster?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, just for the fun I tried to write a recursive function to do this; here's the result (power_sum(2000, 2) answers in about 10s on my machine, so though it's probably not optimal, it's still not too bad).

```
from math import inf
def power_sums(total, p, max_allowed=inf):
    nmax = min(int(total**(1/p)), max_allowed)
    for i in range(nmax, 0, -1):
        if (ip := i**p) == total:
            yield [i]
        else:
            for x in power_sums(total - ip, p, i-1):
                yield [i] + x
```

Comment: Oh, and just now I discovered Alain T.'s answer... I should learn to read :)