# Python - Count all combinations of K numbers from 1-N whose sum is equal to N

Tags: python, algorithm

How do i count all combinations of k numbers from 1-n whose sum is equal to n? Like for n = 10, k = 3, we have (1, 2, 7), (1, 3, 6), (1, 4, 5), (2, 3, 5)

I've tried using itertools.combination but it grows really fast for big numbers

Comment: Your question is a particular case of this one: [Writing integers as sum of kth power distinct integers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76180770)

Comment: are permutations counted multiple times? Or is (1,2,7) =(2,1,7)?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Writing integers as sum of kth power distinct integers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76180770/writing-integers-as-sum-of-kth-power-distinct-integers)

Comment: Do the numbers need to be distinct? I see you left (2,2,6) off your example.

Comment: Just count combinations or create them all?

Comment: You should include your `itertools.combination` solution in the question. It's ok that it's too slow, the point is to show *some* effort from you and to have a reference to compare with. Probably also would've avoided the downvotes, and maybe people will retract them if you add it now. And tell us what "big numbers" you need to solve.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_%28number_theory section Restricted number of parts, or https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangle_of_partition_numbers

Answer (score 2):

The smallest number we can make with k distinct positive integers is choose(k+1, 2).

Let r(n,k) = n - choose(k+1, 2).

Then the count of ways of forming n from k distinct integers is equal to the count of ways of summing k nonnegative non-necessarily-distinct integers to get r(n,k). The idea is we start with 1, 2, 3, ..., k, and then allocate r(n,k) to these starting integers in a nondecreasing manner.

E.g., 10, 3:

```
1 + 2 + 3 = choose(4,2) = 6, so r(10,3) = 10-6 = 4.
4 = 0+0+4, 0+1+3, 0+2+2, 1+1+2
(1,2,3) + (0,0,4) = (1,2,7)
(1,2,3) + (0,1,3) = (1,3,6)
(1,2,3) + (0,2,2) = (1,4,5)
(1,2,3) + (1,1,2) = (2,3,5)
```

So we've reduce the problem to counting the number of ways of summing k nonnegative integers to get r(n,k). Answered [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/217597/number-of-ways-to-write-n-as-a-sum-of-k-nonnegative-integers)

Ruby code (including util functions):

```
def choose(n, k)
  return 0 if k > n
  result = 1
  1.upto(k) do |d|
    result *= n
    result /= d
    n -= 1
  end
  return result
end

def count_partitions_nozeroes(n, k, cache = {})
  return 1 if k==0 && n==0
  return 0 if n <= 0 || k <= 0

  # Check if the result is already memoized
  if cache.key?([n, k])
    return cache[[n, k]]
  end

  # Calculate the result
  result = count_partitions_nozeroes(n-1, k-1, cache) + count_partitions_nozeroes(n-k, k, cache)

  # Memoize the result for future use
  cache[[n, k]] = result
  return result
end

def count_partitions_zeros(n,k)
  return count_partitions_nozeroes(n+k, k)
end

def solve(n,k)
  r = n - choose(k+1,2)
  return count_partitions_zeros(r,k)
end
```

Sample results

```
> solve(10,3)
=> 4

> solve(200,10)
=> 98762607

> solve(2000,10)
=> 343161146717017732

> solve(2000,100) # correct that there's no solution
=> 0

> solve(2000,40)
=> 2470516759655914864269838818691

> solve(5000,50)
=> 961911722856534054414857561149346788190620561928079

> solve(9000,100)
=> 74438274524772625088229884845232647085568457172246625852148213
```

Here's a simpler Ruby version that avoids recursion (other methods unchanged). It gives the same results as above. A few results for larger numbers shown below. This version is O(n*r).

```
def count_partitions_nozeroes(n, k)
  n_to_k_to_count = Hash.new{|h, n| h[n] = Hash.new{|h2, k| h2[k] = 0}}
  n_to_k_to_count[n][k] = 1
  
  (n).downto(1) do |cur_n|
    n_to_k_to_count.delete(cur_n + 1) # delete old keys to save space
    n_to_k_to_count[cur_n].keys.each do |cur_k|
      n_to_k_to_count[cur_n - 1][cur_k - 1] += n_to_k_to_count[cur_n][cur_k] if cur_n >= 1 && cur_k >= 1
      n_to_k_to_count[cur_n - cur_k][cur_k] += n_to_k_to_count[cur_n][cur_k] if cur_n >= cur_k && cur_k >= 0
    end
  end
  return n_to_k_to_count[0][0] 
end
```

Sample results

```
> solve(10_000, 100)
=> 274235043379646744332574760930015102932669961381003514201948469288939

> solve(20_000, 100)
=> 7299696028160228272878582999080106323327610318395689691894033570930310212378988634117070675146218304092757

> solve(30_000, 100)
=> 272832080760303721646457320315409638838332197621252917061852201523368622283328266190355855228845140740972789576932357443034296

> solve(40_000, 200)
=> 1207940070190155086319681977786735094825631330761751426889808559216057614938892266960158470822904722575922933920904751545295375665942760497367

> solve(100_000, 200)
=> 13051215883535384859396062192804954511590479767894013629996324213956689010966899432038449004533035681835942448619230013858515264041486939129111486281204426757510182253404556858519289275662797170197384965998425620735381780708992863774464769

> solve(1_000_000, 200) # getting painfully slow; 3.5 mins
=> 42888085617859871072014862493356049406160707924757355757377806772267059145453158292921778894240787681100326388859698107659554647376742676484705287095709871992089520633323366183055674466048100639306064833776787643422680599710237129079050538847275806415974795879584513402381125673297339438303953873226899382823803432464875135708283442981500695089121425622135472568284901515995857775659213466818843464541496090119445962587194304280691087464026800781
```

Comment: Good observation. I even used choose(k+1, 2) in mine, but didn't think of switching the problem. I wonder whether that helps. Hopefully you or someone else will implement it :-) (I don't intend to.)

Comment: @KellyBundy Challenge accepted. Code & sample results included. We start getting stack level too deep errors somewhere between n=9000 and n=10,000. This could be refactored to avoid recursion, but someone else would have to implement it.

Comment: Bah, why Ruby... question is tagged `python`... And your profile looks like you're much more of a Python than a Ruby guy...

Comment: @KellyBundy I don't know Python. My profile makes it look like I do b/c a lot of algorithm questions are tagged with Python where the OP wants an algorithm not a language specific solution. I can use ChatGPT to translate between languages, though that's risky and may violate S/O guidelines.

Comment: Oh gawd no please no TrashGPT. I might translate it myself during dinner...

Comment: Ok, my Python translation of it is about as fast as my own solutions, both for small inputs and your 9000/100 case. Takes about the same memory as well, 75 MB vs my 73 MB.

Comment: @KellyBundy Thanks for translating; one of these days I'll learn Python... I added non-recursive code which should let the OP do much larger inputs than the recursive version.

Comment: I'll look at that later. Is it slower or faster than the recursive one?

Comment: @KellyBundy I can only test for small inputs since recursive is only good up to n about 9k, but for (9000, 50), the new version takes 0.25 s vs 0.84 for the old version.

Answer (score 1):

A recursive approach with caching can produce results in a reasonable time:

```
from functools import lru_cache

@lru_cache(None)
def countNK(n,k,t=None):
    t = n if t is None else t                    # track target partial sum
    if k == 0:  return int(t==0)                 # empty set can sum to zero
    if t < 1 :  return 0                         # valid target only
    if k > n :  return 0                         # not enough values
    return countNK(n-1,k,t)+countNK(n-1,k-1,t-n) # combine counts
```

- recursion needs to aim for a target using progressively smaller values of `n`
- it also needs to do that for shorter combinations after removing each value from the target
- this will combine the same calculations multiple times, hence the caching

...

output:

```
print(countNK(10,3))     # 4

print(countNK(200,10))   # 98762607
```

*If you need to process large values of `n` (e.g. 500+), you'll either need to increase the recursion limit or convert the function to an iterative loop*

Answer (score 1):

Benchmark with n=100 and all k from 0 to 100, `Kelly*` are my solutions:

```
  2.5 ±  0.1 ms  Kelly
  2.8 ±  0.2 ms  Kelly2
  3.5 ±  0.2 ms  Dave_translated_by_Kelly
295.0 ± 23.7 ms  Alain
```

Let c(n, k) be the number of combinations with sum n with k different numbers 1 or larger.

We get: `c(n, k) = c(n-k, k) + c(n-k, k-1)`

You want sum n with k different numbers 1 or larger. You either use the number 1 in the combination or you don't.

- If you *don't* use 1, then you want sum n with k different numbers 2 or larger. Imagine you had such k numbers. Subtract 1 from each of them, then you have sum n-k with k different numbers 1 or larger. That's c(n-k, k).
- If you *do* use 1, then you want remaining sum n-1 with k-1 different numbers 2 or larger. Imagine you had such k-1 numbers. Subtract 1 from each of them, then you have sum (n-1)-(k-1) = n-k with k-1 different numbers 1 or larger. That's c(n-k, k-1).

The faster solutions with Dave's case n=9000, k=100:

```
469.1 ±  9.2 ms  Kelly2
478.8 ± 17.0 ms  Kelly
673.4 ± 18.8 ms  Dave_translated_by_Kelly
```

Code ([Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=zVbNjuNEEL5xMC9R2j2svZNk7MBIEBG0aBGXFSskjlFkdexyYsXutrrbI7KjeRIue4E7r8Bj8DRU_9juTMJoERcszcTurv781VdfdfvX37uTPgj-8eNvva7mX_31-WclVvAOm-YU8xkck1UEdNUVHGG9htQ9mkui7iWHzMxxOwfYKITURrwpWHFAe2sAixDMA3L4hkBfQ3y8yRK4vYXlNB28IA3XWBLZ1bhsHOQwX8PxKVFPAW783TxLosvpKIpewk8SC9F2vUbQB4Sd6HmpoBLSPr4wxBeLxQvYMcq3oH_RKNryP6nW1jznOb0op3XQ1ErHrCj6tm-YxlgyvkerVpL8G5ED1M1x-_8Q2fD9rmE1Dzm_aWSf25zi94JjMmVGFdDv31HscabXdm6ip0kqbnhrqBWYSSephivXS9CSFUfQTO5RQ8ekrlkDqm8vFEhXI--a61iv12lyBQ_bTp9AEVjBuAECLeADShECaipDBhNgeo2bB7xnTV0OBAVvTufMvqVkPw2ICw3IRb8_GMwe1UW1BlnnmRE2uTkboD895wkBUTPsapLVTqvoGkJQ1u_ZPeakMlfGtWW-O-Vn-0nka3oQQuFFu1B6q3NXSlR9Y4rszGfasKSKgGuHjNZTRwx28MGvyRLnI7e3ayj9kPVuFubhgkZqJqvcekPXgqucC1NQVJbtDKxFidDDY8Cc7AGMl8DpZnXeL64PTa8T96O9C3KMXLXeHpB8abxC2J40-Zk1Ell5ghZbUX_AcgD0jUY6WDZT_q4uZmxjQrYjPmsKu48ELzjX95m055ltZp-67e9ngo-TSsnw-h8d_zA7U8mqJ74IvXLbWMCbCJ2R_JQ6GQamSIOjQpde53pzdM51gEo09xiut1vLfPAqGW22TJ5FdgzkzGH6qAHW9ciu3hPsD4z2qCiqel4oerR74cydIf5nOfvHVooicgDhOJYDhv3dZCsqeSVFa5-1EI2Cuu2E1DBur744LqzWKM_CpiPHBei6xWGuQ1nlNmuUwJSdc1FKM00HVl2MOC0ySknpEu8jP6ROarjdF-aofSskHbaao1KR8QOfOvtu6OrKds3luLnwl46Wj8mnWy_zMG89ZtaO4jw917z5qycLzcWUImnGmLV_m-H9c4fUi5TOgnZ-yqCXiurf1G2t42VKVxIZaUxZHqoVbLZPmDzardJopuLK56NN9IY2L8jwC_e5YeIVqYVlbOE21TbZrO6229CE1asHI3WsVbK6W2TVI_z5BzxY3e3Yl3asVfDKSpxPUi7vAokncpNE-2JRiKahpONJGp0ST0MnGAv9OEgff006zCAzYoz1ItefV-BJdbM0LO-ElRmooD6DHAvWdcidPHFCvarpbWM6XjubFS3H09pK7t_QSXOwD0WYQbXIc85azPPEfQ77r-Lh6_hv)):

```py
def Kelly(n, k):
    if k == 0:
        return 1 if n == 0 else 0
    @cache
    def c(n, k):
        if n < k * (k+1) // 2:
            return 0
        if k == 1:
            return 1
        n -= k
        return c(n, k) + c(n, k-1)
    return c(n, k)


# Precompute the bounds for the "n < ..." base case
def Kelly2(n, k):
    if k == 0:
        return 1 if n == 0 else 0
    min_n_for_k = list(accumulate(range(k+1)))
    @cache
    def c(n, k):
        if n < min_n_for_k[k]:
            return 0
        if k == 1:
            return 1
        n -= k
        return c(n, k) + c(n, k-1)
    return c(n, k)


def Alain(n, k):
    @lru_cache(None)
    def countNK(n,k,t=None):
        t = n if t is None else t                    # track target partial sum
        if k == 0:  return int(t==0)                 # empty set can sum to zero
        if t < 1 :  return 0                         # valid target only
        if k > n :  return 0                         # not enough values
        return countNK(n-1,k,t)+countNK(n-1,k-1,t-n) # combine counts
    return countNK(n, k)


def Dave_translated_by_Kelly(n, k):

  def choose(n, k):
    if k > n: return 0
    result = 1
    for d in range(1, k+1):
      result *= n
      result //= d
      n -= 1
    return result

  def count_partitions_nozeroes(n, k, cache = {}):
    if k==0 and n==0: return 1
    if n <= 0 or k <= 0: return 0

    # Check if the result is already memoized
    if (n, k) in cache:
      return cache[n, k]

    # Calculate the result
    result = count_partitions_nozeroes(n-1, k-1, cache) + count_partitions_nozeroes(n-k, k, cache)

    # Memoize the result for future use
    cache[n, k] = result
    return result

  def count_partitions_zeros(n,k):
    return count_partitions_nozeroes(n+k, k)

  def solve(n,k):
    r = n - choose(k+1,2)
    return count_partitions_zeros(r,k)

  return solve(n, k)


big = False

funcs = Alain, Kelly, Kelly2, Dave_translated_by_Kelly

if big:
    funcs = funcs[1:]

from functools import lru_cache, cache
from itertools import accumulate
from time import perf_counter as time
from statistics import mean, stdev
import sys
import gc

# Correctness
for n in range(51):
    for k in range(51):
        expect = funcs[0](n, k)
        for f in funcs[1:]:
            result = f(n, k)
            assert result == expect

# Speed
sys.setrecursionlimit(20000)
times = {f: [] for f in funcs}
def stats(f):
    ts = [t * 1e3 for t in sorted(times[f])[:5]]
    return f'{mean(ts):5.1f} ± {stdev(ts):4.1f} ms '
for _ in range(25):
    for f in funcs:
        gc.collect()
        t0 = time()
        if big:
           f(9000, 100)
        else:
            for k in range(101):
                f(100, k)
        times[f].append(time() - t0)
for f in sorted(funcs, key=stats):
    print(stats(f), f.__name__)
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's introduce a function: `f(n,k,s)`=number of combinations of `k` numbers from 1 to `n`, having `s` as their sum.

To solve the task we need to calculate `f(n,k,n)`.

The function may be calculated recursively. All combinations can be split into two groups: with and without the max number. That gives us `f(n,k,s)=f(n-1,k-1,s-n)+f(n-1,k,s)`. The recursion may stop in the following cases:

- n<k -> 0 (we don't have enough numbers)
- k=1, s>n -> 0 (every number is too small)
- k=1, s<1 -> 0 (every number is too small)
- k=1, 1<=s<=n -> 1 (there is only one suitable number)
- s<0 -> 0

There are `N^2*k` possible combinations of arguments, so if we cache the already calculated values, we will be within `O(N^3)`.

Comment: @KellyBundy, yes, one case I haven't considered - when s is 0 and we need to use one number, thanks :)

Comment: Thanks. Looks correct now but somehow it's very slow compared even to Alain's. For example for n=100 and k=51, it causes 1,623,275 different combinations of arguments. More than `N^2*k`. [Code](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=hVFBasMwEKRXvWKPNpWDRAmUYIXe-4RQjGtLjZC9MpIMcb_SSy7tE_qYvqayo6btyQKBNDPM7s6-fQxTOFo8n9_HoIr7r5tP5WwPasQmWNt50P1gXYCmbo6SkFYq6OuT7jljrIpcJ3uJQbbV81Q9yq6bMqRg8h2BeLQCA0IA24GTYXQIfMZwwUB2XgJbhA8X-_k5V1DRxFCfXJITluZqw_4SRggONbbg97imKPmKgpfCl-LXh19VCYi9FZyaeH2B-W36xmbJf1HEMKegNstolUZls5wQZV3MRCO4Gl9ktmUUtndp0MFpDJmhawlHZs74wJ82zeic168yv6wvbfFnm98).

Comment: @KellyBundy, is this after caching function results?

Comment: Yes. The cache is also where that number comes from (`f.cache_info()` in the linked code).

Comment: @KellyBundy, apparently, it goes into negative values for `s`, I've added one more stopping condition, not for `f(100,51,100)` it gives 2651 entries

Comment: Ok, and it's about as fast as Alain's now (no wonder, as they're pretty much the same now).